# stack smashing detected in bandwidthTest.cu in CUDA SDK

Tags: cuda, nvcc

I want to run the bandwidthTest inside the CUDA SDK. It is terminated by **stack smashing detected** error. How can I solve this problem?????
 I use the make command to run this program and make the file. I cannot change anything inside the code.

Comment: I don't have an answer for this, but I must say that "Stack smashing detected" is one of the best error messages I've ever heard of!

Comment: I've certainly never heard of that error message.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345670/stack-smashing-detected

Comment: More importantly, did you change anything in the example before you compiled and ran the example ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use GDB to see where it is happening.  Are you using the latest CUDA, 4.2? I found that some of my CUDA code would have stack smashing errors when I upgraded from CUDA 4.0.  Going back to CUDA 4.0 fixed my issues.