# How to read first 256 bits from a file to store them in two arrays

Tags: c++, c, io, buffer, fread

I am coding a cipher, for which key file is 256 bit long. Out of which 128 bits have to go in key and 128 into IV. 
I am explicitly defining the sizes of those arrays and then reading, and still output I get is Key having like 148 bits set while IV has lesser thus. and in the end it gives stack smashing error.

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[]) {

    if(argc < 4 || !argv[1] || !argv[2]) {
        cout << "Usage: Encoding: " << argv[0] << " [plaintext-file] [key-file] [cipher-file]" << endl;
        cout << "Usage: Decoding: " << argv[0] << " [cipher-file] [key-file] [plaintext-file]" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    unsigned char key[16], iv[16];
    unsigned long i;

    // read input file and size etc
    FILE* in_file = fopen(argv[1],"rb");
    if(!in_file) {
        cout << "Error opening read file" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    fseek(in_file,0,SEEK_END);
    unsigned int msglength = ftell(in_file);
    cout << "Msglength:" << msglength << endl;

    unsigned char * mem_ptr =  (unsigned char*)malloc(msglength);
    if(!mem_ptr) {
        cout << "Error allocating memory" << endl;
        fclose(in_file);
        return 0;
    }

    rewind(in_file);
    fread(mem_ptr,1,msglength,in_file);
    fclose(in_file);

    // read keyfile etc
    FILE* key_file = fopen(argv[2],"rb");
    if(!key_file) {
        cout << "Error opening key file" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    fseek(key_file,0,SEEK_END);
    unsigned int key_size = ftell(key_file);
    cout << "Key Size:" << key_size << endl;
    unsigned char * key_ptr = (unsigned char*)malloc(key_size);
    if(!key_ptr) {
        cout << "Error allocating memory" << endl;
        fclose(key_file);
        return 0;
    }

    rewind(key_file);
    fread(key_ptr,1,key_size,key_file);

    cout << "sizeof key"<<sizeof(key)<<"  sizeof iv" << sizeof(iv) << endl;
    for (i=0; i<256; i++) {
        if (i<128) key[i] = key_ptr[i];
        else iv[i-128] = key_ptr[i];
    }
    cout << key_ptr << endl;
    cout << "Key:" << key << endl << "IV:" << iv << endl;
}
```

Output

```
Msglength:15
Key Size:257
sizeof key16  sizeof iv16
abcdefgh12345678abcdefgh12345678abcdefgh12345678abcdefgh12345678abcdefgh12345678abcdefgh12345678abcdefgh12345678abcdefgh12345678abcdefgh12345678abcdefgh12345678abcdefgh12345678abcdefgh12345678abcdefgh12345678abcdefgh12345678abcdefgh12345678abcdefgh12345678

Key:abcdefgh12345678abcdefgh12345678abcdefgh12345678abcdefgh12345678abcdefgh12345678abcdefgh12345678abcdefgh12345678abcdefgh12345678abcdefgh12345678
IV:abcdefgh12345678abcdefgh12345678abcdefgh12345678abcdefgh12345678abcdefgh12345678abcdefgh12345678abcdefgh12345678abcdefgh12345678

*** stack smashing detected ***: ./a.out terminated
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Any idea where am I going wrong?

Comment: i changed declaration to  key[128] etc, and initialized to 0 and the stack smashing is gone, however the key and IV aren't still the same length

Answer (score 0):

The size of your `key` and `iv` are both 16.

```
unsigned char key[16], iv[16];
```

So this is no good.

```
for (i=0; i<256; i++) {
    if (i<128) key[i] = key_ptr[i];
    else iv[i-128] = key_ptr[i];
}
```

You're going wrong there, by writing past the end of both those arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You have a buffer overflow: you define `key` and `iv` as `unsigned char[16]` but in your `for` loop you try to access them as if they were `unsigned char[128]`.

Are you confusing bits and bytes at some point?

Answer (score 0):

As per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345670/stack-smashing-detected) **Stack Smashing is actually a protection mechanism used by gcc to detect buffer overflow attacks**

and i could see

```
unsigned char key[16], iv[16];
```

is uninitialized may be you can consider initializing them to zero or NULL

also

```
  for (i=0;i<256;i++) {
      if (i<128) key[i] = key_ptr[i];
      else iv[i-128] = key_ptr[i];
    }
```

There is no NULL termination in this case perhaps you can look at these to get a bit more idea