# c stack smashing detected on file managing

Tags: c, file, stack-smash

I'm having problem with my program. The variables are written in italian, I'm sorry!
I have to handle the penalties phase of a football game. If in the first five penalties the teams end tie, they will go for penalties to the end.

```
    if (retiPrimaSquadra != retiSecondaSquadra){
        buffer = fopen("buffer.txt", "w");
        fprintf(buffer, "%d-%d", retiPrimaSquadra, retiSecondaSquadra);
        fclose(buffer);
        return 0;
    }   else {
        printf("Risultato secondo tempo supplementare: %d - %d\n\n", retiPrimaSquadra, retiSecondaSquadra);
        printf("RIGORI\n");

        int rigoreA=0, rigoreB=0;
        char vRigoreA[5];
        char vRigoreB[5];
        int rigore=0;
        int i=0;

        vRigoreA[i]='x';

        //printf("%c", vRigoreA[i]);
        for(i=0; i<5; i++){
        //tiro prima squadra
            rigore = (rand() % 101);
            if(rigore <= 75){
                rigoreA++;
                retiPrimaSquadra++;
                vRigoreA[i]='x';
            }
            else{
                vRigoreA[i]='o';
            }
        //tiro seconda squadra
            rigore = (rand() % 101);
            if(rigore <= 75){
                rigoreB++;
                retiSecondaSquadra++;
                vRigoreB[i]='x';
            }
            else{
                vRigoreB[i]='o';
            }
        //stampa xo
        printf("%c %c\n", vRigoreA[i], vRigoreB[i]);
        }
        //risultato 5 rigori
        printf("%d - %d\n", rigoreA, rigoreB);

        char enter = '\0';
        while(enter != '\n'){
            enter = getchar();
        }

        //OLTRANZA
        while(rigoreA==rigoreB){
            //tiro prima squadra
            rigore = (rand() % 101);
            if(rigore <= 75){
                rigoreA++;
                retiPrimaSquadra++;
                vRigoreA[i]='x';
            }   else {
                vRigoreA[i]='o';
            }

            //tiro seconda squadra
            rigore = (rand() % 101);
            if(rigore <= 75){
                rigoreB++;  
                retiSecondaSquadra++;
                vRigoreB[i]='x';
            }
            else{
                vRigoreB[i]='o';
            }
        //stampa xo
        printf("%c %c\n", vRigoreA[i], vRigoreB[i]);

        }

        printf("check\n");  
    }

    buffer = fopen("buffer.txt", "w");
    fprintf(buffer, "%d-%d", retiPrimaSquadra, retiSecondaSquadra);
    fclose(buffer);

}
```

The program runs with no errors if it doesn't enter in the last "while". Otherwise, after finishing the while cycle, when it goes to right the results in the buffer.txt file, it gives me a stack smashing detected problem. I really don't know how to handle it, cause it seems so stupid that if it doesn't enter the while it goes fine!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stack smashing detected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345670/stack-smashing-detected)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `i` to access your `vRigoreA` array in the while (`vRigoreA[i]='x';`). However, `i` is set to `5` after your `for`-loop, so you are accessing stack memory not belonging to the array. At the end of the function, the debugger detects that out-of-bounds writes happened.