# error: expression must have struct or union type in c

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I've been working on a code to store names and grades of students, then recall the grade when the students' names are entered.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 10
#define M 2

struct a
{
     char name[50];
     int grade;
};

int main()
{
    int i;
    int j;
    struct a A[N][M];

    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
         printf("Please Enter Students' Names:/n");
            scanf("%s", &A[i].name);
    }
    for(j=0;j<M;j++)
    {
        printf("Please Enter Students' Grades:/n");
            scanf("%d", &A[j].grade);
    }
    printf("Which Student's Grades Would You Like To View?/n");
        if(scanf("%s", *A[i].name))
        {
            printf("Their Grade Is:%d/n", *A[j].grade);
        }
    return 0;
}
```

I've been getting these errors:

```
hw2problem2.c(21): error: expression must have struct or union type
                        scanf("%s", &A[i].name);
                                     ^
hw2problem2.c(26): error: expression must have struct or union type
                        scanf("%d", &A[j].grade);
                                     ^
hw2problem2.c(29): error: expression must have struct or union type
                if(scanf("%s", *A[i].name))
                                ^
hw2problem2.c(31): error: expression must have struct or union type
                        printf("Their Grade Is:%d/n", *A[j].grade);
                                                       ^
compilation aborted for hw2problem2.c (code 2)
```

Any help with the errors or the program in general would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You defined `struct a A` as a two dimensional array, and only specified
one dimension in `scanf("%s", &A[i].name);` and `scanf("%d", &A[j].grade);`.

You have a couple of other issues, like `scanf("%s", &A[i].name);`... where the 
`&` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

Your program should be like this

```
for(i=0;i<N;i++)
{
   for(j=0;j<M;j++)
   {
    printf("Please Enter Students' Grades:/n");
        scanf("%d", &A[i][j].grade);
    printf("Please Enter Students' Names:/n");
        scanf("%s", &A[i][j].name);

    }
}
```

Because, `A[i]` is of type `struct a*`, not `struct a`. It should be A[i][j]

Logically, your array should be 1-D. Hence, loop should like:

```
struct a A[N];

for(i=0;i<N;i++)
{
     printf("Please Enter Students' Names:/n");
        scanf("%s", &A[i].name);
}
for(j=0;j<N;j++)
{
    printf("Please Enter Students' Grades:/n");
        scanf("%d", &A[j].grade);
}
```

If it is subject wise, then it should be 2D and use nested loop as shown.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use `2D` array. Simply try this..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 3

struct a
{
 char name[50];
 int grade;
};

int main()
{
int i;
struct a A[N];
    char sname[50];
for(i=0;i<N;i++)
{
     printf("Please Enter Students' Names:/n");
        scanf("%s", A[i].name);
}
for(i=0;i<N;i++)
{
    printf("Please Enter Students' Grades:/n");
        scanf("%d",&A[i].grade);
}

     printf("Which Student's Grades Would You Like To View?/n\n");
     printf("Enter the name...\n");
     scanf("%s",sname);
  for(i=0;i<N;i++)
  {
    if(strcmp(A[i].name,sname)==0)
    {
    printf("%s grade is %d\n",A[i].name,A[i].grade);
    break;
    }
    else
    {
    if(i==N-1)
    printf("No such a name in your list...\n");
    }
  }
 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Test case: `A[i].name` is more than 10 characters and `sname` is searched using the same, Will lead to Stack Smashing, since size of `sname` is 10 and you would be scanning more than that value, [See Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345670/stack-smashing-detected) . Also `unused variable j`.

Comment: in general not a good idea to use scanf and %s together, easy to get buffer overrun. better to use fgets/sscanf