# How to determine where this address comes from on 64-bit macOS application

Tags: objective-c, assembly, x86, x86-64

So I'm currently debugging an issue, and trying to figure out how this could happen.

Here is the assembly for a method in the obj-c runtime, called `objc_msgsend()`

```
libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend:
    0x7fff9084a0c0 <+0>:   testq  %rdi, %rdi
    0x7fff9084a0c3 <+3>:   je     0x7fff9084a140            ; <+128>
    0x7fff9084a0c6 <+6>:   testb  $0x1, %dil
    0x7fff9084a0ca <+10>:  jne    0x7fff9084a14b            ; <+139>
    0x7fff9084a0cd <+13>:  movabsq $0x7ffffffffff8, %r11
    0x7fff9084a0d7 <+23>:  andq   (%rdi), %r11
    0x7fff9084a0da <+26>:  movq   %rsi, %r10
    0x7fff9084a0dd <+29>:  andl   0x18(%r11), %r10d
```

I'm using Xcode's lldb to view the registers and addresses.

Here is the interesting output I get, when I first check out the registers at offset +0 (**expected**):

```
(lldb) register read
r11 = 0x00007fff74a940f0  (void *)0x00007fff74a94118: NSObject
```

After offset +13 (**expected**):

```
(lldb) register read
r11 = 0x00007ffffffffff8
```

After offset +23 (**not expected**):

```
(lldb) register read
r11 = 0x0000000100761138  (void *)0x0000000100761160: GTMOAuth2WindowController
```

And then if I `po` the registers at this point:

```
(lldb) po $rdi
<GTMOAuth2WindowController: 0x6100001c2850>

(lldb) po &$rdi
0x000000010bc2b3b8

(lldb) po $r11
GTMOAuth2WindowController

(lldb) po &$r11
0x000000010bc2b3b8
```

So here's where I'm lost; after offset +23, what is that address when I `register read`?
`0x0000000100761138`.   I would've expected it to have `0x6100001c2850`, the location of the object from the dereference at `+23`

If I `po $r11` it prints out the class name (which is expected because we're looking at the `isa` property), and if I print the location in memory for the pointer, it doesn't match the address in `register read`, it matches the address of `%rdi` (expected).

Comment: You may be interested in joining [reverseengineering.se].

Comment: It looks interesting, but already 100% of the questions I've seen there I have no idea what's going on haha.  I don't even think I have enough knowledge to properly ask a question if I had it.  Still trying to figure things out.  Will keep that stackexchange in mind though thanks ^^

Comment: Feel free to join Reverse Engineering if you want, or not, but just to be clear, this question (and others like it) are perfectly on-topic for Stack Overflow, so you can also keep asking them here, if you prefer. (But probably best not to post the same questions on both sites, as there is a significant overlap of users and we don't want the information fragmented!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That address in `%r11` after `<+23>`, `0x0000000100761138`, is the address of the class object that represents your `GTMOAuth2WindowController` class.

When you define a class at compile time (with `@interface` and `@implementation`), there's a special object at runtime that represents the class. In fact it's called a “class object” and is a real object just like all the objects you created. This means that the class object can itself respond to messages. When you said `po %r11` after `<+23>`, the debugger sent the `description` message to the class object. The class object's `description` method returns the name of the class as an `NSString`, so the debugger printed the name of the class.

[You can learn more about class objects here](http://sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2009/04/14/objc_explain_Classes_and_metaclasses.html). The image link on that page is broken in Chrome but you can click it to see a pdf.

Comment: Makes sense, it took me like 4 reads to understand the hampster emporium, but I think I got it.  So last follow-up question, why is it when I printed the location of the pointer to the class (`po &$r11`), it returned to me the location of the pointer to the instance? `0x000000010bc2b3b8` and **not** the location of the pointer to the class? `0x0000000100761138`

Comment: Printing `&$r11` doesn't make any sense, because registers (like `$r11`) don't have addresses. I don't think it has any real meaning. It's just an artifact of the way lldb is implemented.