# Why does this code give me a SIGABRT error? C Programming

Tags: c, sigabrt

```
#include "framework.h"
#include <stdio.h>
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Computes and returns the length of a string
//
// @param text string to check
//
// @return length of the string
//
int stringLength(char *text);

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Changes a string to upper case
//
// @param text string to modify
//
void toUpper(char *text);


//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
int stringLength(char *text)
{
    int  string_length = 0;

    while (text[string_length] != '\000')
        string_length++;

    return string_length;
}

// Main Function
//
int main()
{
    char key[MAX_KEY_LENGTH] = {};
    int string_len = 0;

    do {
        printf(KEY_PROMPT);
        gets(key);
        string_len = stringLength(key);
        if (string_len <= MAX_KEY_LENGTH && string_len > 0)
        {
            break;
        }
    } while (string_len > MAX_KEY_LENGTH || string_len < 0);
}
```

This is my code.
Always when i first put in a string thats too long
(eg. "Student StudentStudent StudentStudent StudentStudent StudentStudent Student")
and then one which is "correct"
(eg. "Student Student")

it gives me this error: (look at picture)

[error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jEsO.png)

Comment: What is your `MAX_KEY_LENGTH`?

Comment: Never use `gets`, it is no longer part of the standard C library. Please read [Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used) The first absurd entry `"Student StudentStudent StudentStudent StudentStudent StudentStudent Student"` breaks it.

Comment: You have a stackoverflow, and it should not happen for such small string, is your code for a microcontroller ?

Comment: Hey, thanks for trying to help me first of all!

Comment: My MAX_KEY_LENGTH is 25

Comment: What can i use instead @WeatherVane

Comment: @phoenixstudio not really, the final result should be a very simple encrypter and decrypter. (assignment for university)

Comment: You can use `fgets()` but remember it also contains the newline.

Comment: Please post the contents of `framework.h`

Comment: regarding: `char key[MAX_KEY_LENGTH] = {};`   This causes the compiler to output: *untitled1.c:35:32: warning: ISO C forbids empty initializer braces [-Wpedantic]*  when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings. ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same results

Comment: the function: `stringlength()` is not needed.  Rather call the `string.h` function: `strlen()`

Comment: OT: regarding: `void toUpper(char *text);`  the header file: `ctype.h` contains the function: `toupper()` which would be a much better choice.  Note: that function is not called anywhere in the posted code.

Comment: regarding; `printf(KEY_PROMPT);`  What is `KEY_PROMPT`?

Comment: regarding: `while (string_len > MAX_KEY_LENGTH || string_len < 0);`  the variable `string_len` can NEVER be less than 0 as the function: `string_length()` starts that value at 0 and counts upward

Comment: the whole `do...while` loop can be replaced with: `fgets( key, sizeof( key ), stdin );  key[ strcspn( key, "\n" ) } = '\0; size_t length = strlen( key );`

Answer (score 0):

why are you getting 'stack smashing'?

this statement:

```
gets(key);
```

keeps placing more and more characters into memory.  so your input:

```
Student StudentStudent StudentStudent StudentStudent StudentStudent Student
```

overruns the input buffer: `key[]`  The result is undefined behavior (and can lead to a seg fault event.)  As you can see, the overrun of the input buffer `key[]` corrupted the stack.  Going around the loop again does not 'magically' fix the corrupted stack.

Therefore, use `fgets()` rather than `gets()`  As `gets()` does not know when to stop inputting more characters while `fgets()` is given a specific stop point.

Strongly suggest reading: [man fgets](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) for the details of that function

Answer (score 0):

I think you have buffer overflow errors. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1347464/10365816), hopefully this helps you.