# What unix signal causes the "*** stack smashing detected ***: terminated" message

Tags: c

As far as I know The cause of this signal is attempting to find give more data than the specified amount to an array. Right now, I'm trying to write a program that catches the signal, but what i'm doing wrong is I'm catching the Abort signal rather than whatever signal causes "stack smashing" I don't expect to get a paragraph of an answer since I'm just asking for a name, and I don't know where I'm not looking.
This is my code if it matters;

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include<unistd.h>

void func(char ** argv) {
        char arr[2]; //here's the source of the problem i'm inventing, only two chars allowed
        strcpy(arr, argv[1]);
        return;
}
void handle_fault(int signal) {
        printf("Bad Access\n");
        exit(-1);
}
void handle_abort(int no) {
        printf("Max two chars\n"); //I dont want to see the "*** stack smashing detected ***: terminated" error at all if possible
        exit (-2);
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        signal(SIGSEGV, handle_fault);
        signal(SIGABRT, handle_abort);
        func(argv);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: The real question is, why do you not want to see that message? `./a.out blablablabla 2>/dev/null` will work.

Comment: No reason at all, I just want to see if there's a way

Comment: None. It's not a signal

Comment: @paladin I'm looking for a way to catch the signal within the code and not manipulate some options when running it, I just want to know what the signal name is if there is any

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345670/stack-smashing-detected

Comment: @long.kl Thanks, I already got my answer

Comment: The message comes from a library, you may customize that library.

Comment: Not related to the question, but your array is also too small. `only two chars allowed` would require an array with 3 characters to hold a valid string.

Comment: @Gerhardh This is by purpose to get the stack smashed.

Comment: Isn't this something handled internally by the compiler/libs when you kill a stack canary? As in no OS involved.