# How to solve Ruby on Rails error in Dockerized application "stack smashing detected"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, docker-compose

On my M2 Macbook Pro 16-inch, 2023

I have a Dockerized rails app that worked until i updated my Mac Operating System to 13.4.1 (c) (22F770820d).

Now when i load a page on development my re-built and deployed app container, it shuts down with the output:

```
2023-07-24 16:03:33    (0.1ms)  SELECT pg_try_advisory_lock(3213395767516697805);
2023-07-24 16:03:33   ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
2023-07-24 16:03:33   ActiveRecord::InternalMetadata Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "ar_internal_metadata".* FROM "ar_internal_metadata" WHERE "ar_internal_metadata"."key" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["key", "environment"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
2023-07-24 16:03:33    (0.1ms)  BEGIN
2023-07-24 16:03:33    (0.1ms)  COMMIT
2023-07-24 16:03:33    (0.1ms)  SELECT pg_advisory_unlock(3213395767516697805)
2023-07-24 16:03:33   ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
2023-07-24 16:03:36 *** stack smashing detected ***: /usr/local/bundle/bin/rake assets:precompile terminated
2023-07-24 16:03:36 ./entrypoint.sh: line 5:    17 Aborted                 bundle exec rake assets:precompile
2023-07-24 16:03:36 Puma starting in single mode...
2023-07-24 16:03:36 * Version 3.12.1 (ruby 2.5.1-p57), codename: Llamas in Pajamas
2023-07-24 16:03:36 * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
2023-07-24 16:03:36 * Environment: development
2023-07-24 16:03:38 * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000
2023-07-24 16:03:38 Use Ctrl-C to stop
2023-07-24 16:03:44 Started GET "/" for 10.0.0.2 at 2023-07-24 16:03:44 -0400
2023-07-24 16:03:44 Cannot render console from 10.0.0.2! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
2023-07-24 16:03:44   ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
2023-07-24 16:03:44 Processing by PagesController#splash as HTML
2023-07-24 16:03:44   Rendering pages/splash.haml within layouts/application
2023-07-24 16:03:44 *** stack smashing detected ***: puma 3.12.1 (tcp://0.0.0.0:3000) [app] terminated
2023-07-24 16:03:44 ./entrypoint.sh: line 11:    29 Aborted                 bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
```

I have tried uping the docker resources to astronomical numbers with no luck. Here are some of my key docker files:

docker-compose.local.yml:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  web:
    image: game-fuse_web
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile.web.local
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - app
    volumes:
      - '.:/var/www/game-fuse-ast'
    ports:
      - 80:80

  db:
    image: postgres:9.6-bullseye
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - "db:/var/lib/postgresql/data"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_DB=game-fuse_development
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    

  app:
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    image: game-fuse_app
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile.local
    command: ./entrypoint.sh
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    working_dir: /app
    depends_on:
      - db

    
volumes:
  db:
```

Dockerfile.local:

```
FROM ruby:2.5.1-slim

ENV TZ=America/New_York


# Allow recently archived stretch to be accessed

RUN echo "deb http://archive.debian.org/debian stretch main" > /etc/apt/sources.list && \
    sed -i 's/deb.debian.org/debian.osuosl.org/g' /etc/apt/sources.list && \
    sed -i 's/security.debian.org/debian.osuosl.org/g' /etc/apt/sources.list


RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential cron libpq-dev nodejs git
RUN gem install nokogiri -v 1.12.5
RUN gem install net-protocol -v 0.1.2
RUN gem install net-smtp -v 0.3.0
RUN gem install net-imap -v 0.2.2
#RUN gem install -N rails

# Set an environment variable where the Rails app is installed to inside of Docker image
ENV RAILS_ROOT /var/www/game-fuse

RUN mkdir -p $RAILS_ROOT

# Set working directory
WORKDIR $RAILS_ROOT

# Setting env up
ENV RAILS_ENV='development'
ENV RACK_ENV='development'

# Remove reliance on git:// protocol
RUN git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://

# Adding gems
COPY Gemfile Gemfile 
COPY Gemfile.lock Gemfile.lock
COPY config ./config

# Adding project files
RUN gem install bundler -v 2.3.26

RUN bundle install --jobs 20 --retry 5 

RUN cd $RAILS_ROOT && bundle exec whenever --update-crontab
```

entrypoint.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

bundle exec rake db:migrate

bundle exec rake assets:precompile

#bundle exec whenever --update-crontab

#cron

bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
```

Not really sure where to look and not a lot of results for this error on the internet in the context of Ruby on Rails or Docker.

Comment: "Stack smashing detected" is an indicator that puma is running into a buffer overflow, and the program is protecting you from data leakage/corruption. 3.12.1 is a very old version of Puma; I would suggest you try updating it first.

Comment: Upgraded to rails 7.0.5 and ruby 3.0.3 from Rails 5.2 and it solved my issue. Had to upgrade puma and all my gems with it. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @ChrisHeald if you want to make an official answer you can have the bounty!

Comment: Done as requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Stack smashing detected" is an indicator that puma is running into a buffer overflow, and the program is protecting you from data leakage/corruption. This is likely coming from the compiled Puma binary extension, and is not coming from Ruby or Rails.

3.12.1 is a very old version of Puma; I would suggest you try updating it first.

Answer (score 0):

The error "[stack smashing detected](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1347464/2924562)" is an indication of a stack buffer overflow or some form of memory corruption.
As you already tried increasing the allocated resources, you might wanna randomly check if Rails, Ruby the gems in your docker container are compatible with the updates OS. Or you can try updating the Ruby/Rails/Gems in the Dockerfile

```
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential cron libpq-dev nodejs git ruby-full='a.b.c'
RUN gem install rails -v 'a.b.c'
(where 'a.b.c' is the version you want)
```

then do `docker-compose build` and re run the rails app.