# How to run previous instructions in GDB?

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb

Here I want to ask this question. When I am debugging a program, sometimes I wish I can run a previous instruction again. Like in Microsoft Visual Studio, we can drag the position indicator (remember the yellow arrow) to the previous instruction you want to locate.

For example:

My program is currently at line 72, and suppose line 70 is in the same function that line 72 sits in. Now I want to re-run line 70 again. Is there any way to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried the `reverse-*` commands? (See `help running`.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Go to previous line in gdb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206872/go-to-previous-line-in-gdb)

Comment: Thanks folks, I looked at it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to go to the previous line in GDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206872/how-to-go-to-the-previous-line-in-gdb)

Answer (score 5):

> I want to re-run line 70 again

Use the GDB `jump` [command](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Jumping.html#Jumping).

Answer (score 1):

You can normally call functions within `gdb` with the `call` command:

```
(gdb) call some_function(arg1, arg2);
```

However, if you want to specifically go back the program, you could always find the memory location of the line in question and set the instruction pointer to it.

```
(gdb) set $eip = <some memory address>
```

That being said, I don't know of a way to fully "unwind" the program's state, if that's what Visual Studio does. In other words, any other program state may be different the second time through.

Comment: I don't think Visual Studio totally unwind the variables. However, I tried reverse-*, that work well for me expect the `target record` thing. Otherwise, the message of "Target child does not support this command." is thrown. Any way to set `target record` in advance?

Answer (score 0):

Use gdb command jump, e.g.:

```
jump 70
```