# gdb step debugging a C program

Tags: c, gdb

Consider a case where a function has 10 lines of code and you are doing a step debugging via GDB and are on line six.
You realize that function call at line 4 did some goof up due to which you are at line 5.

Assuming that line 4 function call does not do anything drastic (mem free, etc) you wish to make your SP point @ line 4 and step into that func without re-running that test case.

I have been able to do it by doing registry modification.

What I wanted to know, are there some gdb commands which can help me achieve the above without manual registry mod.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

Use `jump` command as described [here](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gdb/gdb_119.html).

Answer (score 0):

Just set a breakpoint on the line you need (using the break command) and jump to it (using the jump command).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to "step back". This is supported by GDB since version 7. See [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/news/reversible.html), [tutorial](http://www.sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/ProcessRecord/Tutorial) or [related Stackoverflow topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206872/go-to-previous-line-in-gdb).