# Target child does not support this command error when running reverse-step

Tags: debugging, gdb

I'm playing with gdb reverse debug.  So I have a simple C program with main() and foo() which is called in main().

Inside gdb, I did the following

```
b main
record
run
```

And then I step into `foo()` with:

```
s
```

And then I tried to go back with

```
reverse-step
```

That's when I got the error message in the title.

My gdb version is: GNU gdb (GDB) 7.5.91.20130417-cvs-ubuntu

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Also note that GDB now gives an error if you run `record` before `run`: `Process record: the program is not being run.`.

Comment: BTW, just use Mozilla rr nowadays: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206872/how-to-go-to-the-previous-line-in-gdb/46996380#46996380

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must start debugging the program (with the `run` command) before using `record` to start recording. Try

```
b main
run
record
```