# GDB error: "Process record: the current architecture doesn't support record function"

Tags: gdb, reverse-debugging

I'm trying to do reverse execution in GDB, specifically doing `target record` after running my program in gdb as per the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206872/go-to-previous-line-in-gdb), and triggering the following error:

```
Process record: the current architecture doesn't support record function.
```

This seems to be the same issue discussed [here](https://forums.freebsd.org/viewtopic.php?&t=37313) but was never resolved. Here's my gdb version info:

```
alexcannon$ gdb -version
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.6
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [documentation](http://www.sourceware.org/gdb/news/reversible.html):

> Presently, only certain target debugging environments will support reverse debugging. Those targets currently include:
>
> - Native i386-linux ('target record')
> - Native amd64-linux ('target record')
> - Several remote targets, including:
>
>   - moxie-elf simulator
>   - Simics
>   - VMware Workstation 7.0
>   - the SID simulator (xstormy16 architecture)
>   - chronicle-gdbserver using valgrind
>   - UndoDB

Your target: `x86_64-apple-darwin12` is none of the above.

Sorry, not implemented :-(

Comment: bruh, 2021 gdb 11.1 and still no support for macos