# How to set a breakpoint in GDB where the function returns?

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb

I have a C++ function  which has many return statements at various places. How to set a breakpoint at the return statement where the function actually returns ?

And what does "break" command without argument means?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

break without arguments stops execution at the next instruction in the currently selected stack frame. You select strack frames via the `frame` or `up` and `down` commands. If you want to debug the point where you are *actually* leaving the current function, select the next outer frame and break there.

Comment: The breakpoint is set at the current instruction, not the next one. Execution is already stopped if you're executing a command at all. Any breakpoint in the calling function will not occur when the current function is active, unless it is recursion, in which case such debuggging gets confusing.

Comment: How do you “select the next outer frame and break there”? Can you clarify? (Note that the goal is to have a breakpoint *inside* the function (e.g. being able to look at its locals), but just before it returns.)

Answer (score 38):

Contrary to answers so far, most compilers will create a single return assembly instruction, regardless of how many `return` statements are in the function (it is convenient for the compiler to do that, so there is only a single place to perform all the stack frame cleanup).

If you wanted to stop on that instruction, all you have to do is `disas` and look for `retq` (or whatever the return instruction for your processor is), and set a breakpoint on it. For example:

```
int foo(int x)
{
  switch(x) {
   case 1: return 2;
   case 2: return 3;
   default: return 42;
  }
}

int main()
{
  return foo(0);
}


(gdb) disas foo
Dump of assembler code for function foo:
   0x0000000000400448 <+0>: push   %rbp
   0x0000000000400449 <+1>: mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x000000000040044c <+4>: mov    %edi,-0x4(%rbp)
   0x000000000040044f <+7>: mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
   0x0000000000400452 <+10>:    mov    %eax,-0xc(%rbp)
   0x0000000000400455 <+13>:    cmpl   $0x1,-0xc(%rbp)
   0x0000000000400459 <+17>:    je     0x400463 <foo+27>
   0x000000000040045b <+19>:    cmpl   $0x2,-0xc(%rbp)
   0x000000000040045f <+23>:    je     0x40046c <foo+36>
   0x0000000000400461 <+25>:    jmp    0x400475 <foo+45>
   0x0000000000400463 <+27>:    movl   $0x2,-0x8(%rbp)
   0x000000000040046a <+34>:    jmp    0x40047c <foo+52>
   0x000000000040046c <+36>:    movl   $0x3,-0x8(%rbp)
   0x0000000000400473 <+43>:    jmp    0x40047c <foo+52>
   0x0000000000400475 <+45>:    movl   $0x2a,-0x8(%rbp)
   0x000000000040047c <+52>:    mov    -0x8(%rbp),%eax
   0x000000000040047f <+55>:    leaveq 
   0x0000000000400480 <+56>:    retq   
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) b *0x0000000000400480
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400480
(gdb) r

Breakpoint 1, 0x0000000000400480 in foo ()
(gdb) p $rax
$1 = 42
```

Comment: I'm voting for this because it is a useful tidbit, but can the OP tell which `return` in the code was called.

Comment: this, together with reverse-step from @ks1322 is invaluable. You need to do two reverse-steps, and this is why.

Comment: Interesting! I've made a Python command that finds the `retq` and puts a breakpoint there automatically: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31264709/895245

Comment: What if I need the return line instead of return value? Getting both of them is better.

Answer (score 34):

You can use [reverse debugging](http://www.sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/ProcessRecord/Tutorial) to find out where function actually returns. Finish executing current frame, do **reverse-step** and then you should stop at just returned statement.

```
(gdb) record
(gdb) fin
(gdb) reverse-step
```

Comment: According to that page, this requires Linux-x86, and it probably has a formidable performance penalty. +1 anyway, since it's so cool.

Comment: The `rr` tool at http://rr-project.org/ enables reverse debugging via replay on Linux while incurring only about a 1.2x slowdown (according to its website, at least).  It makes a cool thing even cooler.  :)

Comment: @Potatoswatter and on top of that, it completely breaks down in 7.11 if you do most library calls because of lacking AVX support... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528918/gdb-reverse-debugging-fails-with-process-record-does-not-support-instruction-0x/46113472#46113472

Comment: @CiroSantilli, modern glibc's started to use AVX for speed (https://stackoverflow.com/q/42451492/72178). One way to workaround this is to downgrade to older glibc.

Comment: @pnkfelix `rr` works properly with AVX, amazing tool. Added setup example at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46116927/895245

Comment: I cannot use `record` since it cause my gdb session `Aborted (core dumped)`, so I use just the next two instructions,  `fin` and `reverse-step`, but it says "Target multi-thread does not support this command."

Answer (score 12):

**Break on all `retq` of current function**

This Python command puts a breakpoint on every `retq` instruction of the current function:

```
class BreakReturn(gdb.Command):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(
            'break-return',
            gdb.COMMAND_RUNNING,
            gdb.COMPLETE_NONE,
            False
        )
    def invoke(self, arg, from_tty):
        frame = gdb.selected_frame()
        # TODO make this work if there is no debugging information, where .block() fails.
        block = frame.block()
        # Find the function block in case we are in an inner block.
        while block:
            if block.function:
                break
            block = block.superblock
        start = block.start
        end = block.end
        arch = frame.architecture()
        pc = gdb.selected_frame().pc()
        instructions = arch.disassemble(start, end - 1)
        for instruction in instructions:
            if instruction['asm'].startswith('retq '):
                gdb.Breakpoint('*{}'.format(instruction['addr']))
BreakReturn()
```

Source it with:

```
source gdb.py
```

and use the command as:

```
break-return
continue
```

You should now be at `retq`.

**Step until retq**

Just for fun, another implementation that stops when a `retq` is found (less efficient of because no hardware support):

```
class ContinueReturn(gdb.Command):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(
            'continue-return',
            gdb.COMMAND_RUNNING,
            gdb.COMPLETE_NONE,
            False
        )
    def invoke(self, arg, from_tty):
        thread = gdb.inferiors()[0].threads()[0]
        while thread.is_valid():
            gdb.execute('ni', to_string=True)
            frame = gdb.selected_frame()
            arch = frame.architecture()
            pc = gdb.selected_frame().pc()
            instruction = arch.disassemble(pc)[0]['asm']
            if instruction.startswith('retq '):
                break
ContinueReturn()
```

This will ignore your other breakpoints. TODO: can be avoided?

Not sure if it is faster or slower than `reverse-step`.

A version that stops at a given opcode can be found at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31249378/895245

Comment: Somehow, with a recursive function that is called multiple times, this seems to go haywire, and every breakpoint that is supposed to run at the return is called multiple times. (Haven't actually tried it with a simpler function yet...) (On the other hand this actually works, even if the breakpoint is called multiple times, so thank you.)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR weird. Link to a minimal reproducible example if you can.

Comment: Nice implementation of breaking on `retq`, thanks!
Though there may be an issue with if `return val;` is translated into a couple of assembly instructions, with the ones before `retq` rewriting the register where the returned `val` used to be after it was moved to `%rax`, and confusing gdb (and myself).  I'm going to try to get the line numbers of the lines where `retq` is (from the output of `disas /s func`), and to create breakpoints on these line numbers.

Comment: @KirillSpitsyn awesome, let me know if you can improve the code.

Comment: This is great. I just had to change retq to ret

Answer (score 6):

**`rr` reverse debugging**

Similar to GDB `record` mentioned at https://stackoverflow.com/a/3649698/895245 , but much more functional as of GDB 7.11 vs `rr` 4.1.0 in Ubuntu 16.04.

Notably, it deals with AVX correctly:

- [gdb reverse debugging fails with "Process record does not support instruction 0xf0d at address"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528918/gdb-reverse-debugging-fails-with-process-record-does-not-support-instruction-0x/46113472#46113472)
- ["target record-full" in gdb makes "n" command fail on printf with "Process record does not support instruction 0xc5 at address 0x7ffff7dee6e7"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40125154/target-record-full-in-gdb-makes-n-command-fail-on-printf-with-process-recor/46113357#46113357)

which prevents it from working with the default standard library calls.

Install Ubuntu 16.04:

```
sudo apt-get install rr linux-tools-common linux-tools-generic linux-cloud-tools-generic
sudo cpupower frequency-set -g performance
```

But also consider compiling from source to get the latest updates, it was not hard.

Test program:

```
int where_return(int i) {
    if (i)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

int main(void) {
    where_return(0);
    where_return(1);
}
```

compile and run:

```
gcc -O0 -ggdb3 -o reverse.out -std=c89 -Wextra reverse.c
rr record ./reverse.out
rr replay
```

Now you are left inside a GDB session, and you can properly reverse debug:

```
(rr) break main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x56057c458619: file a.c, line 9.
(rr) continue
Continuing.

Breakpoint 1, main () at a.c:9
9           where_return(0);
(rr) step
where_return (i=0) at a.c:2
2           if (i)
(rr) finish
Run till exit from #0  where_return (i=0) at a.c:2
main () at a.c:10
10          where_return(1);
Value returned is $1 = 0
(rr) reverse-step
where_return (i=0) at a.c:6
6       }
(rr) reverse-step
5               return 0;
```

We are now on the correct return line.

Answer (score 4):

If you can change the source code, you might use some dirty trick with the preprocessor:

```
void on_return() {

}

#define return return on_return(), /* If the function has a return value != void */
#define return return on_return()  /* If the function has a return value == void */

/* <<<-- Insert your function here -->>> */

#undef return
```

Then set a breakpoint to `on_return` and go one frame `up`.

Attention: This will not work, if a function does not return via a `return` statement. So ensure, that it's last line is a `return`.

Example (shamelessly copied from C code, but will work also in C++):

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* Dummy function to place the breakpoint */
void on_return(void) {

}

#define return return on_return()
void myfun1(int a) {
    if (a > 10) return;
    printf("<10\n");
    return;   
}
#undef return

#define return return on_return(),
int myfun2(int a) {
    if (a < 0) return -1;
    if (a > 0) return 1;
    return 0;
}
#undef return


int main(void)
{
    myfun1(1);
    myfun2(2);
}
```

The first macro will change

```
return;
```

to

```
return on_return();
```

Which is valid, since `on_return` also returns `void`.

The second macro will change

```
return -1;
```

to

```
return on_return(), -1;
```

Which will call `on_return()` and then return -1 (thanks to the `,`-operator).

This is a very dirty trick, but despite using backwards-stepping, it will work in multi-threaded environments and inlined functions, too.

Answer (score 3):

Break without argument sets a breakpoint at the current line.

There is no way for a single breakpoint to catch all return paths. Either set a breakpoint at the caller immediately after it returns, or break at all `return` statements.

Since this is C++, I suppose you could create a local sentry object, and break on its destructor, though.