# Quickly determine where a function returned

Tags: c, gdb

I have a long C function that can `return` at different lines. Is it possible to have GDB run through the function and print out on what line the function `return`ed? So far I have been going through one line at a time (using `n`), and this is becoming tedious.

Can I dynamically call a function with GDB and know on which line it returned?

Comment: Try adding breakpoints on all return statements. I usually try to follow the one return statement per function rule exactly for the purpose of debugging issues like the one you describe.

Comment: Exact duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649468/setting-breakpoint-in-gdb-where-the-function-returns and that question has a good answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3649698/16509

Comment: @jjrv: Thanks, but I don't have `reverse-step` since I'm working with an embedded device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One nasty trick if you're compiling with GCC and can edit the code would be to do a macro and search+replace all the returns in your editor...

```
int global_return_lineno;
#define return2(x) {global_return_lineno=__LINE__;return(x);}
```

Then call the function and inspect the global variable.