# GDB: Break after function has returned

Tags: c, gdb

Is there a way to tell GDB to break right after a given function has returned?

Comment: You should not create a second question for an issue you're already covering, especially just 5 minutes after the first one. It's preferrable that you edit your previous question to include additional details about your situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're about to execute the function, `n[ext]`. If you're inside, `fin[ish]` will stop when it returns and show the return value.

Comment: Thanks. But this [does not work for my use case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10501121/gdb-script-not-working-as-expected).

Comment: If it does not work for your use case, then the problem here is that you asked a new question with no information about your use case instead of following up on your existing question.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a breakpoint to the function then `finish` to step out.

Comment: Thanks. But this [does not work for my use case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10501121/gdb-script-not-working-as-expected).