# How to execute next inside commands list and then another command?

Tags: gdb, breakpoints

When I set a breakpoint in GDB and attach a command-list to it, if I execute a "next" in this command-list, the following commands are ignored, which is normal (See https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Break-Commands.html#Break-Commands).

However, it could be very useful for me to override this limitation... So, is it possible to execute a "next" in the commands block and also the following commands ?

e.g. :

```
break 8
  commands
    next
    set i = i+1
    continue
  end
```

Comment: If you just do "next" unconditionally after the breakpoint hit, you could just as well set the breakpoint on line 9, right? Could you show a use case that better demonstrate your constraints?

Comment: Yes, i thought about that but in some cases, it does not work. For example :

`if(i > 0) {
    i++;
 } else {
    i--;
}`

In this case, if I want to break just after the i++ instruction, and I set the breakpoint at this line, the "real" breakpoint will be put at the "i-- line" (which is in the else block). Then, if the condition is satisfied, the "i-- line" will never be reached and so my breakpoint will never be hit.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to execute finish and then another command from inside commands?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10501121/how-to-execute-finish-and-then-another-command-from-inside-commands)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't `next` or `cont` from breakpoint command lists, but you can write a "stop event handler" in Python then resume inferior execution from there. See the self-contained example below:

## buggy.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int i;
    i = atoi(getenv("i"));

    if (i > 0) {
        i++;
    } else {
        i--;
    }
    printf("i: %d\n", i);
    return 0;
}
```

## next-after-break-on-conditional.gdb

```
set confirm 0
set python print-stack full

python import gdb

file buggy

break 8
python
conditional_bpnum = int(gdb.parse_and_eval('$bpnum'))
def stop_handler(event):
    if not isinstance(event, gdb.BreakpointEvent):
        return
    if conditional_bpnum not in set(x.number for x in event.breakpoints):
        return
    gdb.write('i: %d\n' % (gdb.parse_and_eval('i'),))
    gdb.execute('next')
    gdb.write('GDB: incrementing "i" from debugger\n')
    gdb.execute('set variable i = i+1')
    gdb.execute('continue')

gdb.events.stop.connect(stop_handler)
end

run
quit
```

## Sample Session

```
$ gcc -Os -g3 buggy.c -o buggy
$ i=0 gdb -q -x next-after-break-on-conditional.gdb
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4004e3: file buggy.c, line 8.

Breakpoint 1, main () at buggy.c:9
9           i++;
i: 0
11          i--;
GDB: incrementing "i" from debugger
i: 1
[Inferior 1 (process 7405) exited normally]
```

## Implementation Notes

`stop_handler()` will be called whenever GDB stops so you *MUST* test that GDB stopped for the specific breakpoint before issuing commands.

If I compile with `-O3`, I'd get the dreaded "value has been optimized out" error for `i` and `set variable i = i+1` would fail. So watch out for this as usual. (gcc-4.9.2, gdb-7.8.2 on Fedora 21, x86-64)

## References

- [GDB Manual > Setting Breakpoints](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Breaks.html#Set-Breaks): "The debugger convenience variable ‘$bpnum’ records the number of the breakpoint you've set most recently"
- [GDB Manual > Events in Python](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Events-In-Python.html#Events-In-Python): `gdb.events.stop.connect(stop_handler)`
- [GDB Manual > Breakpoints in Python](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Breakpoints-In-Python.html#Breakpoints-In-Python): `gdb.Breakpoint.num`

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It works ! Actually, for my specific problem, I created a new command in python and I execute `gdb.execute("next")` inside this command, but it's your answer that made me think of that.

Answer (score 0):

> So, is it possible to execute a "next" in the commands block and also the following commands ?

Not with GDB, no.