# How to put breakpoint at function return

Tags: gcc, gdb, breakpoints

I know the function name which is called. But not from where it is called. I want to put a breakpoint using gdb at return of this function. How to proceed?

Is there any specific command, or some series of steps?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649468/setting-breakpoint-in-gdb-where-the-function-returns

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use reverse debugging using this one:

```
(gdb) fin
(gdb) reverse-step
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are merely want to know what parent function called your specific function, put a breakpoint at the top of the child function in question. Once it breaks, use `backtrace` (or just `bt`) to see a full trace of the calls made to get to that point in execution.