# How can I use gdb to catch the moment when a function returns false?

Tags: gdb

How can I detect the moment when my function `bool f()` returns false?

`f` has complex `if` statements that returns true or false, and it is costly to make breakpoints for all parts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting breakpoint in GDB where the function returns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649468/setting-breakpoint-in-gdb-where-the-function-returns)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try with a bit of Python code:

```
import gdb
class FunctionFinishBreakpoint (gdb.FinishBreakpoint):
    def __init__ (self):
        gdb.FinishBreakpoint.__init__(self, gdb.newest_frame(), 
                                      internal=True)
        self.silent = True 

    def stop(self):
        #print("after: {}".format(int(self.return_value)))
        return not int(self.return_value)

class FunctionBreakpoint(gdb.Breakpoint):
    def __init__ (self, spec):
        gdb.Breakpoint.__init__(self, spec)
        self.silent = True

    def stop (self):
        #print("before")
        FunctionFinishBreakpoint() # set breakpoint on function return

        return False # do not stop at function entry

FunctionBreakpoint("test")
```

Save that in a `finish.py` file, edit it to your needs and source it from GDB, or run it between `python ... end` or in `python-interactive` (`pi`).

This code creates a `FunctionBreakpoint`, that triggers `FunctionBreakpoint.stop` eachtime function `test` is hit. The callback is silent, and only creates a `FunctionFinishBreakpoint`, that stops at the end of the current frame (ie, at the end of your function). That second stop calls `FunctionFinishBreakpoint.stop`, which tests if the return value evaluates to true or false. If it is "not true", it tells GDB to stop the execution.

Documentation references:

- [Manipulating breakpoints using Python](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Breakpoints-In-Python.html)
- [Finish Breakpoints](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Finish-Breakpoints-in-Python.html#Finish-Breakpoints-in-Python)

(`gdb.FinishBreakpoint` was added to GDB Python interface for that very purpose, by myself :-)

(last time I checked, there was an efficiency problem with these FinishBreakpoint, you may notice it if your function is called very often)