# reverse debugging in gdb

Tags: debugging, gdb

I tried to use rc in gdb and it gave me an error "Target native does not support this command". I searched some and I found that using record target full will record execution step but I've got this error:
[image] What is this error and how can I previously executed step?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["target record-full" in gdb makes "n" command fail on printf with "Process record does not support instruction 0xc5 at address 0x7ffff7dee6e7"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40125154/target-record-full-in-gdb-makes-n-command-fail-on-printf-with-process-recor)

Comment: gdb does not support avx instructions in reverse debugging yet.