# Track all variables for execution of function in gdb

Tags: c, automation, scripting, gdb, gdbinit

I want to track the state of all the variables in a function in C.

I know I can use info  commands in gdb to get all the variables state at the current context.

And I can use gdbinit to automate the gdb.

But what I want to do is set a breakpoint at the function and then after executing each line print execute the info  command.

Basically, I want to set 2 breakpoints: one at the start of a function and one at the end of the same function(I don't know how to this) and execute line-by-line between these 2 points.

I want something like this in my `gdbinit`:

```
b <func_name>
commands
while <inside the function>:
   info locals
   next
end
run
```

Is there a way to have the while loop shown above?

Comment: Are you looking for [gdb breakpoint commands](https://sourceware.org/gdb/download/onlinedocs/gdb/Break-Commands.html#Break-Commands)? It allows you to configure one or more commands to run every time a breakpoint is hit.

Comment: @kaylum Yeah something like this. I already looked at the documentation. But what I want is something different. I edited my question to reflect on what I am looking for.

Comment: Did you try to use `display` and `undisplay`?

Comment: This is not quite what I am looking for.`display` would show the state of the variable when I do something right(such as entering `next`). But I want to automate this so that I don't write next multiple times in my commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Basically, I want to set 2 breakpoints: one at the start of a function and one at the end of the same function(I don't know how to this) and execute line-by-line between these 2 points.

You can find how to set the breakpoint at the end of the function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3655520/50617). However, that isn't necessary here.

You can use `$_caller_is()` GDB convenience function to finish executing current routine, and stop after it has returned.

Example:

```
int fn()
{
  int sum = 0;
  for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
    sum += j;
  }
  return sum;
}

int main()
{
  return fn() - 10;
}
```

And now GDB session:

```
gdb -q ./a.out
Reading symbols from ./a.out...
(gdb) b 4
Breakpoint 1 at 0x1130: file t.c, line 4.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /tmp/a.out

Breakpoint 1, fn () at t.c:4
4     for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
(gdb) while $_caller_is("main")
 >info locals
 >next
 >end
j = 1431654464
sum = 0
5       sum += j;
j = 0
sum = 0
4     for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
j = 0
sum = 0
5       sum += j;
j = 1
sum = 0
4     for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
j = 1
sum = 1
5       sum += j;
j = 2
sum = 1
4     for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
j = 2
sum = 3
5       sum += j;
j = 3
sum = 3
4     for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
j = 3
sum = 6
5       sum += j;
j = 4
sum = 6
4     for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
j = 4
sum = 10
7     return sum;
sum = 10
8   }
sum = 10
main () at t.c:12
12    return fn() - 10;
(gdb) q
```

P.S. For all but toy problems, this method of debugging will be both grossly inefficient *and* insufficient (it is rare for the interesting state to be captured entirely by local variables).

Comment: Hi,
So there are two things:
1) ```while true```  has a syntax error. so can you please change it to ```while 1```
2) This doesn't stop at the next breakpoint, it just continues till the end of program execution.

Comment: Thank you very much.