# Watchpoint a fixed address

Tags: debugging, gdb, watchpoint

For my current embedded application I am trying to put GDB watch point at a fixed memory address.

As an example, my application updates the following address: 0x10793ad0. In order to be sure which part of the code is corrupting the value, I tried

```
watch 0x10793ad0
```

Even though GDB does not print any error after this, it is not able to break during execution even though I verified the value is getting modified at between start and end of execution.

**Questions:**

1. Can I really put watch at a fixed address? I didn't come across any such example online.
2. Is this the right way or am I missing something?

Comment: for reference: what you did there, was to watch an expression: `0x10793ad0` -> the literal value. that value is constant of course, does not change and therefore no break triggered.

__hint:__ use `disp(lay) <expression>` to check the result before using it to break on

Answer (score 120, accepted):

The right way to set watchpoint on address is **watch *0x10793ad0**. See [gdb doc](http://sourceware.org/gdb/download/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Watchpoints.html#Set-Watchpoints)

Comment: If you're using a fixed address because you want to watch a variable outside the local scope, use `watch -l localptr->member` instead.

Answer (score 2):

**`-l/-location` example**

In this answer I'd like to further highlight the `-l/-location` option previously [mentioned by Nathan Kidd in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649438/watchpoint-a-fixed-address#comment45005957_3650362).

If you don't use this option, then doing:

```
watch mylocalvar
```

makes GDB break as soon as `mylocalvar` goes out of scope, and then automatically delete that memory watchpoint and continue execution.

`-l` can therefore be very useful when you know that there is just one instance of some value being passed around by reference, typically a `this`-like `struct`.

Consider:

main.c

```c
typedef struct {
    int i;
} MyThing;

void MyThing_init(MyThing *s, int i) {
    i += 1;
    s->i = i;
    i += 2;
    i += 3;
}

int MyThing_get_i(MyThing *s) {
    return s->i;
}

int main(void) {
    MyThing s;
    MyThing_init(&s, 1);
    MyThing_init(&s, 2);
    MyThing_init(&s, 3);
    MyThing_init(&s, 4);
    return MyThing_get_i(&s);
}
```

Compile and debug:

```bash
gcc -ggdb3 -O0 -o main.out main.c
gdb -nh -ex 'tb MyThing_init' -ex r main.out
```

This leaves as at:

```
6           i += 1;
```

Now if we do:

```
watch s->i
```

it shows up under:

```
(gdb) i b
Num     Type           Disp Enb Address            What
2       hw watchpoint  keep y                      s->i
```

then the first `c` stops just after the variable is modified as desired:

```
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Hardware watchpoint 2: s->i

Old value = 0
New value = 2
MyThing_init (s=0x7fffffffccb4, i=2) at main.c:8
8           i += 2;
```

but the second `c` stops when `MyThing_init` returns and explains to us that it deleted the watchpoint:

```
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Watchpoint 2 deleted because the program has left the block in
which its expression is valid.
main () at main.c:19
19          MyThing_init(&s, 2);
```

which we can confirm with:

```
(gdb) i b
No breakpoints or watchpoints.
```

and so running the program with `c` again will just run until it exits.

But if we instead use `-l`:

```
watch -l s->i
```

which shows up under `i b` as:

```
(gdb) i b
Num     Type           Disp Enb Address            What
2       hw watchpoint  keep y                      -location s->i
```

then the watchpoint does not get deleted, and we break on every call:

```
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Hardware watchpoint 2: -location s->i

Old value = 2
New value = 3
MyThing_init (s=0x7fffffffccb4, i=3) at main.c:8
8           i += 2;
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Hardware watchpoint 2: -location s->i

Old value = 3
New value = 4
MyThing_init (s=0x7fffffffccb4, i=4) at main.c:8
8           i += 2;
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Hardware watchpoint 2: -location s->i

Old value = 4
New value = 5
MyThing_init (s=0x7fffffffccb4, i=5) at main.c:8
8           i += 2;
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Hardware watchpoint 2: -location s->i

Old value = 5
New value = 32767
0x00007ffff7c44fd6 in __run_exit_handlers (status=5, listp=0x7ffff7dfe860 <__exit_funcs>, run_list_atexit=run_list_atexit@entry=true, run_dtors=run_dtors@entry=true) at ./stdlib/exit.c:43
43      ./stdlib/exit.c: No such file or directory.
```

This technique is particularly powerful in conjunction with [Mozilla rr reverse debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470434/how-does-reverse-debugging-work/53063242#53063242), because then what usually happens is you are at a point of failure like:

```
b MyThing_get_i
```

and you notice a bad value for something, say `s->i`, and then you want to know what was the last thing that set that bad value. Once in `rr`, you can immediately answer that with:

```
watch -l s->i
rc
```

It is a thing of great beauty.

Tested on Ubuntu 23.10, GCC 13.2.0. GDB 14.