# How can I save the debugging status in gdb?

Tags: gdb

So that next time I just can continue from where I stopped?

Comment: One technique that has some overlap with the use case of  is reverse debugging: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470434/how-does-reverse-debugging-work/53063242#53063242 While Mozilla rr cannot save and restore a snapshot to disk, it does save every non-deterministic event to disk, and guarantees that every execution will be the exact same, so if you can reach the execution point again, you're fine.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to use checkpoint

http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Checkpoint_002fRestart.html#Checkpoint_002fRestart

Comment: this doesn't work,I can't save the checkpoint to an external file,so I can't continue debugging another day.

Answer (score 1):

What about generate-core-file???