# How do I analyze a program's core dump file with GDB when it has command-line parameters?

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb, coredump

My program operates like this:

```
exe -p param1 -i param2 -o param3
```

It crashed and generated a core dump file, `core.pid`.

I want to analyze the core dump file by

```
gdb ./exe -p param1 -i param2 -o param3 core.pid
```

But GDB recognizes the parameters of the EXE file as GDB's input.

How do I analyze a core dump file in this situation?

Comment: Are you sure your `exe` is not a shell script (to set some variables, etc..) like e.g. `firefox` is on Linux?

Comment: `file core.pid` would tell which command actually dumped core, and it's typically *not* necessary to add the command line parameters (as they are part of the core).

Answer (score 269, accepted):

You can use the core with GDB in many ways, but passing parameters which is to be passed to the executable to GDB is not the way to use the core file. This could also be the reason you got that error. You can use the core file in the following ways:

`gdb <executable> <core-file>` or `gdb <executable> -c <core-file>` or

```
gdb <executable>
...
(gdb) core <core-file>
```

When using the core file you don't have to pass arguments. The crash scenario is shown in GDB (checked with GDB version 7.1 on Ubuntu).

For example:

```
$ ./crash -p param1 -o param2
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
$ gdb ./crash core
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.1-ubuntu
...
Core was generated by `./crash -p param1 -o param2'. <<<<< See this line shows crash scenario
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  __strlen_ia32 () at ../sysdeps/i386/i686/multiarch/../../i586/strlen.S:99
99    ../sysdeps/i386/i686/multiarch/../../i586/strlen.S: No such file or directory.
    in ../sysdeps/i386/i686/multiarch/../../i586/strlen.S
(gdb)
```

If you want to pass parameters to the executable to be debugged in GDB, use `--args`.

For example:

```
$ gdb --args ./crash -p param1 -o param2
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.1-ubuntu
...
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/@@@@/crash -p param1 -o param2

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__strlen_ia32 () at ../sysdeps/i386/i686/multiarch/../../i586/strlen.S:99
99    ../sysdeps/i386/i686/multiarch/../../i586/strlen.S: No such file or directory.
    in ../sysdeps/i386/i686/multiarch/../../i586/strlen.S
(gdb)
```

Man pages will be helpful to see other GDB options.

Most useful commands are:

- `bt` (backtrace)
- `info locals` (show values of local variables)
- `info registers` (show values of CPU registers)
- `frame X` (change to stack frame *X*)
- `up` and `down` (navigate in the stack frame (call chain))

Answer (score 58):

Simple usage of GDB, to debug coredump files:

```
gdb <executable_path> <coredump_file_path>
```

A coredump file for a "process" gets created as a "core.pid" file.

After you get inside the GDB prompt (on execution of the above command), type:

```
...
(gdb) where
```

This will get you with the information, of the stack, where you can analayze the cause of the crash/fault.
**Other command,** for the same purposes is:

```
...
(gdb) bt full
```

This is the same as above. By convention, it lists the whole stack information (which ultimately leads to the crash location).

Answer (score 35):

**GDB minimal runnable example**

simple.c

```
int myfunc(int i) {
    *(int*)(0) = i;
    return i - 1;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    (void)argv;
    int i = argc * 2;
    int ret = myfunc(i);
    return ret;
}
```

Compile:

```
gcc -ggdb3 -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -o simple.out simple.c
```

To generate the core file, we first have to run in the current terminal:

```
ulimit -c unlimited
```

which means "dump core files without any size limit". This exists because core files contain the entire memory of the crashing process, and so they could be very large.

Tested as of Ubuntu 16.04, you have to remove a pre-existing core file (TODO mandatory? I forgot):

```
rm -f core
```

Tested as of Ubuntu 22.04, you need to fight against apport to get your core file: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1349047/where-do-i-find-core-dump-files-and-how-do-i-view-and-analyze-the-backtrace-st/1442665#1442665 e.g. with:

```
echo 'core' | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
```

Then we run the program:

```
./simple.out
```

and the terminal contains:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

The core file has been generated. On Ubuntu 16.04 the file is named just:

```
core
```

On Ubuntu 22.04 after `echo 'core' | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern` the file is named as:

```
core.<pid>
```

where PID is the process ID, a number, e.g.:

```
core.162152
```

I think this is because of a Linux kernel update that started adding the `.pid` suffix. TODO confirm.

We can now use the core file as either

```
gdb simple.out core
gdb simple.out core.162152
```

and now we enter a GDB session which is exactly as things would have been when the program crashed, except of course we can't "continue running" as the program is about to end:

```
#0  0x0000557097e0813c in myfunc (i=2) at simple.c:2
2           *(int*)(0) = i; /* line 7 */
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000557097e0813c in myfunc (i=2) at simple.c:2
#1  0x0000557097e0816b in main (argc=1, argv=0x7ffcffc4ba18) at simple.c:9
(gdb) up
#1  0x0000557097e0816b in main (argc=1, argv=0x7ffcffc4ba18) at simple.c:9
9           int ret = myfunc(i);
(gdb) p argc
$1 = 1
```

So after running `bt`, we immediately understand where the code was when it crashed, which is sometimes good enough to solve the bug.

As you can see from the example, you are now able to inspect program memory at the time of crash to try and determine the cause of failure, the process virtual memory is entirely contained in the core file.

Tested in Ubuntu 16.04 and 22.04 amd64.

**You can also run the program through GDB directly**

If the problem is easy to reproduce (i.e. crashes fast and deterministically), and you can easily control the command line (i.e. not a program that is called by another program which you don't want/can't modify) then the best approach is to just run the program through GDB:

```
gdb -ex run simple.out
```

and when the signal is received, GDB by default breaks at the signal cause, and we would be left in a situation that looks exactly as when we used the core file.

**Direct Binutils analysis**

Let's try to observe the contents of the core file without GDB to understand it a bit better. Because we can.

Let's create a program that prints its some of its own memory addresses so we can correlate things:

main.c

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int myfunc(int i) {
    *(int*)(NULL) = i; /* line 7 */
    return i - 1;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    /* Setup some memory. */
    char data_ptr[] = "string in data segment";
    char *mmap_ptr;
    char *text_ptr = "string in text segment";
    (void)argv;
    mmap_ptr = (char *)malloc(sizeof(data_ptr) + 1);
    strcpy(mmap_ptr, data_ptr);
    mmap_ptr[10] = 'm';
    mmap_ptr[11] = 'm';
    mmap_ptr[12] = 'a';
    mmap_ptr[13] = 'p';
    printf("text addr: %p\n", text_ptr);
    printf("data addr: %p\n", data_ptr);
    printf("mmap addr: %p\n", mmap_ptr);

    /* Call a function to prepare a stack trace. */
    return myfunc(argc);
}
```

Program output:

```
text addr: 0x4007d4
data addr: 0x7ffec6739220
mmap addr: 0x1612010
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

First:

```
file core
```

tells us that the `core` file is actually an ELF file:

```
core: ELF 64-bit LSB core file x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), SVR4-style, from './main.out'
```

which is why we are able to inspect it more directly with usual binutils tools.

A quick look at the [ELF standard](http://www.sco.com/developers/devspecs/gabi41.pdf) shows that there is actually an ELF type dedicated to it:

```
Elf32_Ehd.e_type == ET_CORE
```

Further format information can be found at:

```
man 5 core
```

Then:

```
readelf -Wa core
```

gives some hints about the file structure. Memory appears to be contained in regular program headers:

```
Program Headers:
  Type           Offset   VirtAddr           PhysAddr           FileSiz  MemSiz   Flg Align
  NOTE           0x000468 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x000b9c 0x000000     0
  LOAD           0x002000 0x0000000000400000 0x0000000000000000 0x001000 0x001000 R E 0x1000
  LOAD           0x003000 0x0000000000600000 0x0000000000000000 0x001000 0x001000 R   0x1000
  LOAD           0x004000 0x0000000000601000 0x0000000000000000 0x001000 0x001000 RW  0x1000
```

and there is some more metadata present in a notes area, [notably `prstatus` contains the PC](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89933/how-to-view-core-files-for-debugging-purposes-in-linux/202443?noredirect=1#comment1048179_202443):

```
Displaying notes found at file offset 0x00000468 with length 0x00000b9c:
  Owner                 Data size       Description
  CORE                 0x00000150       NT_PRSTATUS (prstatus structure)
  CORE                 0x00000088       NT_PRPSINFO (prpsinfo structure)
  CORE                 0x00000080       NT_SIGINFO (siginfo_t data)
  CORE                 0x00000130       NT_AUXV (auxiliary vector)
  CORE                 0x00000246       NT_FILE (mapped files)
    Page size: 4096
                 Start                 End         Page Offset
    0x0000000000400000  0x0000000000401000  0x0000000000000000
        /home/ciro/test/main.out
    0x0000000000600000  0x0000000000601000  0x0000000000000000
        /home/ciro/test/main.out
    0x0000000000601000  0x0000000000602000  0x0000000000000001
        /home/ciro/test/main.out
    0x00007f8d939ee000  0x00007f8d93bae000  0x0000000000000000
        /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
    0x00007f8d93bae000  0x00007f8d93dae000  0x00000000000001c0
        /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
    0x00007f8d93dae000  0x00007f8d93db2000  0x00000000000001c0
        /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
    0x00007f8d93db2000  0x00007f8d93db4000  0x00000000000001c4
        /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
    0x00007f8d93db8000  0x00007f8d93dde000  0x0000000000000000
        /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
    0x00007f8d93fdd000  0x00007f8d93fde000  0x0000000000000025
        /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
    0x00007f8d93fde000  0x00007f8d93fdf000  0x0000000000000026
        /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
  CORE                 0x00000200       NT_FPREGSET (floating point registers)
  LINUX                0x00000340       NT_X86_XSTATE (x86 XSAVE extended state)
```

`objdump` can easily dump all memory with:

```
objdump -s core
```

which contains:

```
Contents of section load1:

 4007d0 01000200 73747269 6e672069 6e207465  ....string in te
 4007e0 78742073 65676d65 6e740074 65787420  xt segment.text 

Contents of section load15:

 7ffec6739220 73747269 6e672069 6e206461 74612073  string in data s
 7ffec6739230 65676d65 6e740000 00a8677b 9c6778cd  egment....g{.gx.

Contents of section load4:

 1612010 73747269 6e672069 6e206d6d 61702073  string in mmap s
 1612020 65676d65 6e740000 11040000 00000000  egment..........
```

which matches exactly with the stdout value in our run.

Tested in Ubuntu 16.04 amd64, GCC 6.4.0, binutils 2.26.1.

**Mozilla `rr` reverse debugging as the ultimate "core file"**

Core files allow you to inspect the stack at break.

But in general what you really need to do is to go back in time to further decide the root failure cause.

The amazing Mozilla rr allows you to do that, at the cost of a larger trace file, and a slight performance hit.

Example at: [How does reverse debugging work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470434/how-does-reverse-debugging-work/53063242#53063242)

**See also**

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89933/how-to-view-core-files-for-debugging-purposes-in-linux

Comment: TL;DR. Consider actually reading and not just starting with "TL;DR" to sound cool, especially when the question is short and when you respond with such a massive amount of text.

Comment: @ReubenBeeler TL;DR nah, I'll take the coolness points.

Comment: Seriously though, that was used as a synonym to "In summary". Because those three bullet points are a summary, then I jump to an example, so things are repeated later on a bit.

Comment: That is not a synonym to TL;DR as long as the sky is blue. If you mean it to be, I suggest removing "TL;DR" because it leaves the expectation that your response will not be credible

Comment: "TL;DR" implies a very credible answer. The "didn't read" part of it is to be understood as "I, the reader, didn't read", not the author. Anyway, this kind of parlance in English is fairly annoying and should probably be avoided.

Answer (score 25):

Just skip the parameters. GDB doesn't need them:

```
gdb ./exe core.pid
```

Comment: But this doesn't work. The gdb output warning: core file may not match specified executable file.
Failed to read a valid object file image from memory.

Comment: "core file may not match specified executable". Did you modify exe after it produced the core? Did you perhaps rebuild it with different command-line options? It is very important to give GDB the *exact* same binary that produced the core. If you don't, you'll get garbage out.

Comment: Also make sure that the binary being passed to gdb is not stripped. You can run 'file <binary name>' which shows it is stripped or not.

Answer (score 11):

From [RMS's GDB debugger tutorial](http://www.unknownroad.com/rtfm/gdbtut/gdbadvanced.html#CORE):

```
prompt > myprogram
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
prompt > gdb myprogram
...
(gdb) core core.pid
...
```

Make sure your file really is a `core` image -- check it using `file`.

Answer (score 10):

A slightly different approach will allow you to skip GDB entirely. If all you want is a backtrace, the Linux-specific utility ['catchsegv'](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/catchsegv.1.html) will catch SIGSEGV and display a backtrace.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't matter if the executable has arguments or not. To run GDB on any binary with a generated core file, the syntax is below.

```
Syntax:
gdb <binary name> <generated core file>
Eg:
gdb l3_entity 6290-corefile
```

Let me take the below example for more understanding.

```
bash-4.1$ **gdb l3_entity 6290-corefile**

**Core was generated** by `/dir1/dir2/dir3/l3_entity **Program terminated with signal SIGABRT, Aborted.**
#0
#1
#2
#3
#4
#5
#6
#7
#8
#9
#10
(gdb)
```

From the above output, you can guess something about core, whether it is a NULL access, SIGABORT, etc..

These numbers #0 to #10 are the stack frames of GDB. These stack frames are not of your binary. In the above 0 - 10 frames if you suspect anything wrong select that frame

```
(gdb) frame 8
```

Now to see more details about it:

```
(gdb) list +
```

To investigate the issue further, you can print the suspected variable values here at this point in time.

```
(gdb) print thread_name
```

Answer (score 2):

I just use `coredumpctl debug` (on Fedora 32) and it gives me a GDB console to debug my most recent core dump.

Comment: Or `coredumpctl gdb` to load the most recent core dump.

Answer (score 0):

Simply type the command:

```
$ gdb <Binary> <codeDump>
```

Or

```
$ gdb <binary>

$ gdb) core <coreDump>
```

There isn't any need to provide any command line argument. The code dump generated due to an earlier exercise.