# How do I make use of a core dump to find application problems in C/C++?

Tags: c++, debugging, coredump

I don't have any idea how I could find the root cause of a C/C++ linux application's problem using the core files. I understand that core files are genereated when something unexpected happens to an application. But I don't know where to start. Can anybody give me a jump start?

Comment: The first thing I try to get out of a core dump is usually a stack backtrace for all threads, which can be done with tools like gdb or pstack, some of which are platform specific.

Comment: You start with `gdb program core`.  Have you gotten past that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to analyze a program's core dump file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305866/how-to-analyze-a-programs-core-dump-file)

Comment: "teach me to use a debugger" is way too broad for a stack overflow question.  Just search for "gdb core dump"

Answer (score 1):

Some generic help:

Install gdb using :

yum install gdb

**gdb** start GDB, with no debugging les

**gdb program** begin debugging program

**gdb program core** debug coredump core produced by program

**gdb --help** describe command line options

1- First of all find the directory where the corefile is generated.
2- Then use "ls -ltr" command in the directory to find the latest generated corefile. 
3- To load the corefile use

**gdb binary path of corefile**

This will load the corefile.

4- Then you can get the information using "bt" command. For detailed backtrace use "bt full".

5- To print the variables use "print varibale-name" or " p varibale-name"

6- To get any help on gdb use "help" option or use "apropos search-topic"

7- Use "frame frame-number" to go to desired frame number.

8- Use "up n" and "down n" commands to select frame n frames up and select frame n frames down respectively.

9- To stop gdb use "quit" or "q".