# How to extract the error from core dump file

Tags: unix

I am writing a script to find all the core files on production server and check process name from which it came. How can i check in core file from which process it came and what made it to create.
I tried $file "core_file_name" command but it only shows from which process it came.
But i want to dig more in core file and find what made the process crash.

Comment: Hi, you can use gdb for instance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305866/how-to-analyze-a-programs-core-dump-file

Comment: Its highly difficult to find the cause of the crash just by writing a script. Thyere can be lot of complexities that needs to be handled. individually but not all at a time.