# Analysis Of Core Dump Generated By Release Version App

Tags: linux, gdb, release, coredump

From posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305866/how-to-analyze-a-programs-core-dump-file) I have known how to do analysis on core dump files generated by debug version app. And for a core dump file I can also get the call stack by using gdb tool and bt command.

But when using the other commands like info locals, list, print localvariable, etc. I found they display nothing! What surprises me is that this core dump file is as big as the one generated by debug version app and has size of 1.6G bytes!

Is there anyway to get more information including the call stack? Is it possible to see other details regarding the variables in the last function call when core dump generated?

Answer (score 4):

> What surprises me is that this core dump file is as big as the one generated by debug version app and has size of 1.6G bytes!

You shouldn't be surprised by that. The core dump contains modifiable segments of the application memory. The application compiled with debug info will have exactly the same modifiable memory as the application compiled without debug info, and should produce exactly the same core dump (assuming other compilation flags are the same, and that the application is repeatable from run to run).

The debug info is needed to make sense of that memory dump in the debugger. But you can also make sense of that memory dump without debug info, it's just much more manual and tedious.

> Is there anyway to get more information including the call stack?

You said you *already* have the call stack.

The best practice is to *always* build your application with full debug info, e.g.

```
gcc -O2 -g -c foo.cc -o foo.o
gcc -g foo.o bar.o ... -o app
```

Then keep the resulting (large) binary for debugging, but ship a stripped variant of that binary to end-users:

```
cp app app-stripped
strip -g app-stripped   # removes all debug info from app-stripped
```

Now when you get a core dump from app-stripped, use the full-debug `app` to analyze that core.

Alternatively, you can use separate debuginfo files, as documented [here](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Separate-Debug-Files.html).