# Smart Pointers - Segmentation Fault at Program Termination

Tags: c++, pointers, stl, unique, shared

I've been making a state-thingy to replace some much poorer code I've been using. I wanted to be as modern as possible, so I'm using STL wherever appropriate. I decided to use `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr`, which I've never done before. As a result, I've hit a very scary run-time error: `munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x00007fff7b3f08e0` All I know is the error has to do with `free()` and `malloc()`, but I haven't used any of that in my code, so I assume it's coming from inside STL. To make things even stranger, if I put a `std::cout << "Hello World!\n";` at the beginning of main, I just get a `Segmentation fault` My code is relatively small so-far:

state.hpp:

```
#pragma once
#include "state_manager.hpp"

class state{
 using manager_ptr = std::shared_ptr<state_manager>;
protected:
 manager_ptr man;
public:
 const manager_ptr manager() const;
 void manager(manager_ptr&& parent_manager);
};
```

state.cpp:

```
#include "state.hpp"

const state::manager_ptr state::manager() const{
 return man;
}

void state::manager(manager_ptr&& parent_manager){
 man = parent_manager;
}
```

state_manager.hpp:

```
#pragma once
#include <stack>
#include <memory>

class state;

class state_manager{
 using element = std::unique_ptr<state>;
 using container =  std::stack<element>;
protected:
 container states;
public:
 void push(element&& to_push);
 void pop();
 void change(element&& change_to);
};
```

state_manager.cpp:

```
#include "state_manager.hpp"
#include "state.hpp"

void state_manager::push(element&& to_push){
 states.push(std::forward<element>(to_push));
 states.top()->manager(std::shared_ptr<state_manager>(this));
}

void state_manager::pop(){
 states.pop();
}

void state_manager::change(element&& change_to){
 states.pop();
 push(std::forward<element>(change_to));
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "state_manager.hpp"
#include "state.hpp"
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]){
 state_manager test;
 test.push(std::make_unique<state>());
 test.change(std::make_unique<state>());
 test.pop();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger? On Linux, a crash should be [easy to debug](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8305866/1667513) if you can [produce a core dump](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17965/1667513).

Comment: No, I have never used a debugger. It's time to start?

Comment: I would recommend it. If on Linux try [this gdb tutorial](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~gilpin/tutorial/) and if on Windows [try this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79508/Mastering-Debugging-in-Visual-Studio-A-Beginn). Learning this skill will serve you better than any provided solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this line of code:

```
states.top()->manager(std::shared_ptr<state_manager>(this));
```

You are constructing a `shared_ptr` that points to `this`. That means that when the shared_ptr's reference count drops to zero, it will `delete` `this`. This is bad, as the class is not the owner of `this`. In your case, the `this` pointer isn't even allocated by `new`, so the shared_ptr will not be able to delete it.

You could use just a normal C++ pointer for `man` in your `state_manager` class, as it currently doesn't need ownership of the pointer.

Alternatively you need some other way to get a `shared_ptr` or `weak_ptr` that points to `this`, e.g. by passing it in to `push` (which would be weird).