# Segmentation Fault with mkfifo

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, mkfifo

I've got a problem with the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>


int main(int argc, char*argv[]){

    FILE * tube;
    char chaine[10];
    mkfifo("glue", 0666);
    tube = fopen("glue", "r");


    while(1){
        fgets(chaine, 10, tube);
        printf("%s\n", chaine);

    }

}
```

It's a program that mimics a server behavior, however when I run it on my Ubuntu Machine, either Windows 10 Ubuntu subsystem or the normal OS, the mkfifo line returns this error:

```
Segmentation Fault(core dumped)
```

Pls Help!

EDIT:

Forgot to send the version with the mkfifo test:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>


int main(int argc, char*argv[]){

    FILE * tube;
    char chaine[10];
    int errValue = mkfifo("glue", 0666);
    perror("mkfifo");
    if( errValue < 0){
        printf("Error: %d\n", errValue);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    tube = fopen("glue", "r");


    while(1){
        fgets(chaine, 10, tube);
        printf("%s\n", chaine);

    }

}
```

The output of the program is:

```
mkfifo: Operation not permitted
Error: -1
```

And the one of umask is:

```
0000
```

And thank you immensely everyone for participating in this post!!:)

EDIT, PROBLEM SOLVED THANKS TO achal and everyone, thank you sooo much:

-One problem, the core one, was in using a 0022 umask instead of an 0002, thanks achal for this solution.

-The second problem was me using the Ubuntu subsystem for windows and try to run the program from CLI while it was located on the Windows desktop, windows doesn't give pipe permissions for the desktop apparently.

-The solution was to switch to my Ubuntu boot and change the umask and then it worked perfectly:)

Thanks to achal and everyone who participated in this post.

PROBLEM SOLVED.

Comment: Generate a core dump and then analyze it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305866/how-to-analyze-a-programs-core-dump-file-with-gdb

Comment: I'm not sure it is `mkfifo` that causes the segmentation fault, more likely the lines after. However, you don't check the return value of `mkfifo` (which is a big mistake when programming in C, since that's the only way you can handle errors) so there's no guarantee if the function call itself is successful. The same with `fopen`, there's no guarantee it won't be `NULL`.

Comment: Most likely `mkfifo` is failing, and then you're getting an error when you try to open the nonexistent fifo.

Comment: You're probably running the program in a directory you don't have write permission to, so `mkfifo` fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mkfifo()` is a IPC mechanism useful for create a `FIFO` for communicating same or different process.

man pages of `mkfifo()` says "The `mkfifo()` system call creates a new fifo file with name path.  The access permissions are specified by `mode` and `restricted` by the `umask(2)` of the calling process"

As you mentioned in comments in your terminal `umask` value was `0000` means no permission that's why mkfifo() fails, so modify umask value using CLI  according your requirement.

```
xyz@xyz-PC:~$ umask 0002
xyz@xyz-PC:~/s_flow$ umask
0002
```

and modify your code as

```
int main(int argc, char*argv[]){

    FILE * tube;
    char chaine[10];
    int errValue = mkfifo("glue", 0666);
    perror("mkfifo");
    if( errValue < 0){
        printf("Error: %d\n", errValue);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    tube = fopen("glue", "r");
    if(tube == NULL)
    {
     printf("error in opening file :\n");
     return 0;
    }
    while(1){
        fgets(chaine, 10, tube);
        printf("%s\n", chaine);

    }

}
```

Once umask value is set, execute your program.

I hope it helped lot

Comment: I disagree that the `f*()`-filefunctions are not suitable for fifos, why do you think so? The segmentation fault most probably results from the `fopen()` failing and the subsequent `fgets()` dereferences a NULL pointer.

Comment: I did an edit to the post and added the code error returned by mkfifo, pls check the post edited section.

Comment: Used the modified code, however I got this output:/

Comment: mkfifo: Operation not permitted  Error: -1

Comment: Modify the umask value using CLI. . If it is 0000 how it will allow to create fifo file. ..it should be 0002

Comment: FINALLY!!! I changed the Umask and it worked!! Thank you so much, just got to add somethings, will do an edit

Comment: achal, could you please edit your answer as well with the umask solution you suggested and make it a community wiki, it would help a lot of people in my opinion:) Thank you so much again!!!!

Comment: @AbdelghaniBekka your welcome brother. I'm very happy that my posts helped you.

Comment: If really did:)