# Surface Matching never get any results with any data, why?

Tags: c++, opencv, point-clouds, pose

Im trying to get working the Surface Matching Sample code from [surface_matching](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/surface_matching/doc/surface_matching.html). Im able to compile the code then when run with `./surface_matching /home/surface_matching/coke.ply /home/surface_matching/01.ply`

Im running the same code sample as in the link. Code is the followving

```
#include "opencv2/surface_matching.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/surface_matching/ppf_helpers.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core/utility.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
using namespace ppf_match_3d;

static void help(const string& errorMessage)
{
    cout << "Program init error : "<< errorMessage << endl;
    cout << "\nUsage : ppf_matching [input model file] [input scene file]"<< endl;
    cout << "\nPlease start again with new parameters"<< endl;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // welcome message
    cout << "****************************************************" << endl;
    cout << "* Surface Matching demonstration : demonstrates the use of surface matching"
             " using point pair features." << endl;
    cout << "* The sample loads a model and a scene, where the model lies in a different"
             " pose than the training.\n* It then trains the model and searches for it in the"
             " input scene. The detected poses are further refined by ICP\n* and printed to the "
             " standard output." << endl;
    cout << "****************************************************" << endl;
    
    if (argc < 3)
    {
        help("Not enough input arguments");
        exit(1);
    }
    
#if (defined __x86_64__ || defined _M_X64)
    cout << "Running on 64 bits" << endl;
#else
    cout << "Running on 32 bits" << endl;
#endif
    
#ifdef _OPENMP
    cout << "Running with OpenMP" << endl;
#else
    cout << "Running without OpenMP and without TBB" << endl;
#endif
    
    string modelFileName = (string)argv[1];
    string sceneFileName = (string)argv[2];
    
    Mat pc = loadPLYSimple(modelFileName.c_str(), 1);
    
    // Now train the model
    cout << "Training..." << endl;
    int64 tick1 = cv::getTickCount();
    ppf_match_3d::PPF3DDetector detector(0.025, 0.05);
    detector.trainModel(pc);
    int64 tick2 = cv::getTickCount();
    cout << endl << "Training complete in "
         << (double)(tick2-tick1)/ cv::getTickFrequency()
         << " sec" << endl << "Loading model..." << endl;
         
    // Read the scene
    Mat pcTest = loadPLYSimple(sceneFileName.c_str(), 1);
    
    // Match the model to the scene and get the pose
    cout << endl << "Starting matching..." << endl;
    vector<Pose3DPtr> results;
    tick1 = cv::getTickCount();
    // orig detector.match(pcTest, results, 1.0/40.0, 0.05);
    detector.match(pcTest, results, 1.0/40.0, 0.05);
    tick2 = cv::getTickCount();
    cout << endl << "PPF Elapsed Time " <<
         (tick2-tick1)/cv::getTickFrequency() << " sec" << endl;
         
    // Get only first N results
    int N = 2;
    vector<Pose3DPtr> resultsSub(results.begin(),results.begin()+N);
    
    // Create an instance of ICP
    ICP icp(100, 0.005f, 2.5f, 8);
    int64 t1 = cv::getTickCount();
    
    // Register for all selected poses
    cout << endl << "Performing ICP on " << N << " poses..." << endl;
    icp.registerModelToScene(pc, pcTest, resultsSub);
    int64 t2 = cv::getTickCount();
    
    cout << endl << "ICP Elapsed Time " <<
         (t2-t1)/cv::getTickFrequency() << " sec" << endl;
         
    cout << "Poses: " << endl;
    // debug first five poses
    for (size_t i=0; i<resultsSub.size(); i++)
    {
        Pose3DPtr result = resultsSub[i];
        cout << "Pose Result " << i << endl;
        result->printPose();
        if (i==0)
        {
            Mat pct = transformPCPose(pc, result->pose);
            writePLY(pct, "para6700PCTrans.ply");
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
    
}
```

It runs but never gets any results. I got this error

```
$ ./surface_matching /home/admini/surface_matching/coke.ply /home/admini/surface_matching/01.ply 
****************************************************
* Surface Matching demonstration : demonstrates the use of surface matching using point pair features.
* The sample loads a model and a scene, where the model lies in a different pose than the training.
* It then trains the model and searches for it in the input scene. The detected poses are further refined by ICP
* and printed to the  standard output.
****************************************************
Running on 64 bits
Running without OpenMP and without TBB
Training...

Training complete in 0.100169 sec
Loading model...

Starting matching...
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Training is complete and starts matching but then Segmentation fault. What can be the problem? Here the object model file: [image: Coke can model]
And the scene file
[image: Scene file]

What can be the problem?

Comment: Try running this program in a debugger.  Or at the very least, load the core dump in `gdb` and examine the stack to find where your program crashed.

Comment: sorry, Im not familiar with core dump. What do you mean load the core dump in gdb and examine the stack?

Comment: _"Segmentation fault (core dumped)"_ indicates that your process execution state was dumped out before the process was terminated by the operating system.  This is typically because the process did something it's not allowed to (accessing memory for which it does not have permission is a common example).  Look for a file called `core` in the working directory after running this program.  Then read this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8305866/1553090

Comment: ok. Thanks. I think the problem is the scene cloud. In the scene cloud must be only one object

Comment: Hello, have you solved this problem? I encountered the same problem, it turns out that the point cloud loaded doesn't contain normals, so I calculated the normals explicitly, and then it works.

Comment: oh didnt solve. How did you calculate the normal explicitly ?