# Trying to write a Lua module in C on Arch Linux will segfault

Tags: c, linux, lua, archlinux

I wrote the following C file (for lua 5.1) `bar_src.c`:

```c
#include <lua5.1/lua.h>
#include <lua5.1/lauxlib.h>
#include <lua5.1/lualib.h>

static int foo(lua_State *L)
{
  int a = luaL_checknumber(L, 1);
  int b = luaL_checknumber(L, 2);

  lua_pushnumber(L, a + b);

  return 1;    
}

luaL_Reg foolib[] = {
  {"foo", foo},
  {NULL, NULL}
};

int luaopen_bar(lua_State *L)
{
  luaL_register(L, "bar", foolib);
  return 1;
}
```

And compiled it with: `gcc -shared -fpic -o bar.so bar.c -llua5.1`.
However, whenever I try running `require("bar")` in lua, it instantly does `segmentation fault (core dumped)`.

I wanted to try on another system, so I did the same thing on repl.it (which runs on Ubuntu 18.04) and everything worked perfectly, meaning my Linux configuration has an issue.

Edit:
I found the core dump for the segfault in `/var/lib/systemd/coredump`, and loaded it into GDB with `gdb $(which lua) /var/lib/systemd/coredump/core.lua.[file]`, and gdb said:

```
Core was generated by `lua'.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00005620820f3ad3 in lua_pushvalue ()
```

Comment: Have you tried inspecting where the error occurred by loading the core dump in gdb? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305866/how-do-i-analyze-a-programs-core-dump-file-with-gdb-when-it-has-command-line-pa

Comment: I managed to find the coredump file (on arch it is located in `/var/lib/systemd/coredump`). it said:

`Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. #0  0x00005620820f3ad3 in lua_pushvalue ()`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was using the lua 5.4 interpreter, I should have run it with the `lua5 .1` command.

In this example, I used the older version of Lua, Lua 5.1, but the arch package of Lua has 5.1, 5.2, 5.3, and the latest 5.4 installed. Although there isn't much documentation for 5.4, there is a reference manual. The compiler said that the function `luaL_register` was not in Lua 5.4, but I found a replacement called `luaL_newlib()` [in the manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#lual_newlib).

I changed my code to look like this:

```c
#include <lua5.1/lua.h>
#include <lua5.1/lauxlib.h>
#include <lua5.1/lualib.h>

static int foo(lua_State *L)
{
  int a = luaL_checknumber(L, 1);
  int b = luaL_checknumber(L, 2);

  lua_pushnumber(L, a + b);

  return 1;    
}

luaL_Reg foolib[] = {
  {"foo", foo},
  {NULL, NULL}
};

int luaopen_bar(lua_State *L)
{
  luaL_newlib(L, foolib);
  return 1;
}
```

This code compiled perfectly amd when I `require`d it, there were no segfaults.