# Why GDB is crashing my program when break point is hit when using it from VSCode?

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio-code, gdb, vscode-debugger

I'm using VSCode version `1.71.0 784b0177c56c607789f9638da7b6bf3230d47a8c x64` on Ubuntu Linux version `22.04.1 LTS`. I'm compiling with GCC version `11.2.0` but the same problem occurs when the application is compiled with Clang `14.0.0` and `Clang 16.0.0`. My version of GDB is `12.0.90`. I'm using C/C++ `v.1.12.4` and CMake Tools `v1.12.26` plugins for VSCode. I start debugging session with the `CMake: Debug` command by default assigned to the `F5` shortcut. For some time the application I'm debugging started to crash when a breakpoint is hit. The exact message is the following:

```
Aborted (core dumped)
[1] + Aborted (core dumped)      "/usr/bin/gdb" --interpreter=mi --tty=${DbgTerm} 0<"/tmp/Microsoft-MIEngine-In-ifoflcfq.xvl" 1>"/tmp/Microsoft-MIEngine-Out-h4yklwfm.ghy"
```

The same problem does not occur when I'm using GDB from the command line and for that reason, I assume that the problem is related to the integration of GDB with VSCode. I cannot reproduce the problem with a small program. For a small test application, it works fine. At the beginning of debugging session, the following warning is displayed for a small amount of time before the terminal is cleared and the logs of the debugged application started to appear.

```
warning: GDB: Failed to set controlling terminal: Operation not permitted
```

I'm not sure whether it is somehow related to the problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8306805/1587755

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem since couple of days. I have an identical system & toolset & IDE extensions (all at the same version). And I also get a core dump from gdb with a SIGABRT. 
Not sure if it's related to the integration of GDB in with CMakeTools extensions, (but I think I also tried with a `launch.json` configuration with the exact same results). Which let me thinks, it might be related to how vscode invokes GDB in mi-mode.
I'll check if there's a similar issue at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools,

Comment: It looks like the two `Aborted` messages are from a shell, rather than GDB itself.  Usually, when GDB exists with SIGABRT this is because an internal assertion triggered, which should have printed an error somewhere - though if GDB is being run from inside VSCode, I assume that application is consuming the error.  IF a core file has been created you could try `gdb -q -ex 'bt' /usr/bin/gdb -c <COREFILE>` and see if the backtrace includes useful symbols (might need to install debug symbols package for GDB first), then add the backtrace to this question.

Comment: It can also happen when compiler optimization remains switched on for the debug build. It's worth checking that `-O0` is set.

Comment: @bobeff Did you solve the problem? I'm having the exact same problem.

Comment: @JulienVillemure-Fréchette Better to upate the link. No direct issue is seen.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be an issue with version GDB 12.09 and VS Code upgrading GDB to 12.1 by building from source resolved this issue for me as per this

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/103#issuecomment-1151217772