# How can I read the memory of a process in python in linux?

Tags: python, linux, ptrace

I'm trying to use python and python ptrace to read the memory of an external process. I need to work entirely in python, and I've been trying to read and print out the memory of a process in linux.

So for example I've tried the following code, which keeps giving me IO errors:

```
proc_mem = open("/proc/%i/mem" % process.pid, "r")
print proc_mem.read()
proc_mem.close()
```

Mostly I just want to repeatedly dump the memory of a process and look for changes over time. If this is the correct way to do this, then what is my problem? OR is there a more appropriate way to do this?

Comment: This appears to be answered, in detail, at http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6301/how-do-i-read-from-proc-pid-mem-under-linux

Comment: It seems like trying to read the /proc/%i/mem file is not really the way I want to do this. So the other half of my question stands I guess. Is there an appropriate way to do this in python, assuming that I may want to write to the process memory page? I'm using ptrace to start and stop the process.

Comment: This demo program given at this [link](http://www.mail-archive.com/fusil@lists.tuxfamily.org/msg00011.html): seems to be pretty closely related to what I'm trying to do, although I haven't been able to duplicate this quite yet. There is a function in ptrace that searches through a memory map for a byte string.

Comment: Still working on this issue in my *copious* free time. So let me be clearer in answer to larsks, I don't want to just read it, I need to be able to touch it in RAM as well. So I can user ptrace to attach to a process, start and stop etc, but I would like to know how I can reach into the memory space and flip some bits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call a shell command from python - subprocess module

```
import subprocess

# ps -ux | grep 1842 (Assuming 1842 is the process id. replace with process id you get)

p1 = subprocess.Popen(["ps", "-ux"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p2 = subprocess.Popen(["grep", "1842"], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p1.stdout.close()  # Allow p1 to receive a SIGPIPE if p2 exits.
output = p2.communicate()[0]
print output
```

and parse through output to see its memory utilization

Comment: Parsing formatted output doesn't seem to be nearly as clean as using the /proc fs--which is exactly what it is intended for.

Comment: You are right. But depending on the scope of the requirement, isn't it easier to understand a command and parse it than to understand about proc file system?? If not, I guess the link provided by Iarsks answers the question well enough

Comment: This ended up being the closest I could come to what I was thinking of. And more importantly, sufficient for the project I was working on.

Answer (score 1):

> Mostly I just want to repeatedly dump the memory of a process and look for changes over time. If this is the correct way to do this, then what is my problem? OR is there a more appropriate way to do this?

You may be interested in gdb's [reverse debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470434/how-does-reverse-debugging-work), which records all changes to process memory. Here is [the tutorial](https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/ProcessRecord/Tutorial) ([google cache](https://google.com/#q=cache:sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/ProcessRecord/Tutorial)).

There is also [Robert O'Callahan](http://robert.ocallahan.org/)'s [Chronicle](https://code.google.com/p/chronicle-recorder/)/[Chronomancer](https://code.google.com/p/chronomancer/) [work](https://lwn.net/Articles/232769/), if you want to play with the raw recording tools.

Comment: This was also an awesome answer. In fact it would have been my accepted answer except for having already finished my little project using Sudheer's answer.