# How do I follow value propagation through function calls with GDB reverse debugging?

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, dynamic-analysis, reverse-debugging

I am trying to figure out a way to follow the propagation of values through function calls and variable copies in a program using GDB reverse debugging. I have used GDB a lot in the past, but am relatively new to reverse-debugging.

I think it is easiest to frame the question with an example. Take a look at this program.

```
void FnA(int x) {
  printf("x=%d\n", x)
}

void FnB(int y) {
  int y_copy = y;
  FnA(y_copy);
}

void FnC(int z) {
  FnB(z);
}

int main() {
  int i;
  i = 5;
  FnC(i);
}
```

I compile the program, and then spin up GDB to run the compiled executable, using reverse-debugging. I set a breakpoint at the `printf` in `FnA`, then let the program begin executing, which causes me to hit that breakpoint. From here, I want to answer the question "Where was the last time that `x` was written to?" I could do a `watch -l x` and then `reverse-continue`. However, that will just take me to the beginning of `FnA`, because that is where `x` began its lifetime on the stack. What I am *really* interested in is the assignment of `i = 5` all the way back in `main` because that is where `x`'s value originated from. From the time that `i = 5` happened, really the value of `x` was just propagated through function parameters and variable copies, like so: `main:i -> FnC:z -> FnB:y -> FnB:y_copy -> FnA:x`.

Obviously I could figure this out with some GDB-fu combined with human intuition, but I am trying to make this process as automated as possible. I eventually want to try this in more complex software, where using human-intuition and GDB-fu would be rather tedious.

Is there a convenient way to accomplish this in GDB with reverse-debugging? Is GDB capable of automatically figuring out and following these value propagations?

PS: To be specific, am actually using GDB with [rr](http://rr-project.org/). rr is just a wrapper around gdb to allow for deterministic and reproducible execution contexts. I think/hope the core question remains the same, regardless of whether i'm using gdb with or without rr.

Comment: Interesting answers from the author http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470434/how-does-reverse-debugging-work/1535497#1535497

Comment: @MatthewFisher Thanks, I have read some of those answers. None that I have seen answer this particular question though.

Comment: I went and played with this feature.  I didn't actually know that it existed in gdb so thanks for the interesting question.  gdb does not appear to support this sort of functionality.  I've been puzzling on how this could be done while using value semantics.  It is an interesting comp sci problem that appears unsolvable in the general case.  Perhaps some serially consistent cases could be made to work however.