# Anyone tried reverse-debugging in gdb?

Tags: gdb, reverse-debugging

Has anyone tried using the new record/replay and reverse-debugging features in the newly released gdb-7.0?  I am one of the gdb developer/maintainers, and I'm very eager for user feedback!

Comment: It is very slow though - you have to be able to set a break point close to where your actual problem is to enable record, if you can't do this its pretty much unusable. Limited practical application I would say

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522619/bidirectional-or-reverse-debugging

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi I tried it briefly. It make life a lot easier for the cases where either I screwed up some thing while debugging or for run-many-times-find-me bugs

Answer (score 4):

Well, there is now a tutorial to help you get started:
http://www.sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/ProcessRecord/Tutorial

Answer (score 1):

This definitely deserved more attention -- the reverse debugging feature ROCK FREAKING HARD. No sweat. Great work!

For a practical real-world use (and a problem with reverse-debugging), see

[In GDB, how to find out who malloc'ed an address on the heap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333689/in-gdb-how-to-find-out-who-malloced-an-address-on-the-heap/3337579#3337579)

(Problem: it doesn't seem to support any IO (`printf()`, etc.) which makes it practically useless.