# Is there a debugger that lets me step backwards through the code?

Tags: c++, c, debugging

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bidirectional (or reverse) debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522619/bidirectional-or-reverse-debugging)

I've looked up the Omniscient Debugger (http://www.lambdacs.com/debugger/ODBDescription.html), but it's specific to Java. Is there any debugger with this same functionality for native apps, i.e., C/C++?

I haven't made myself clear. I'd like to break on bogus data values/code paths, and then "rollback", debug backwards, until I find the error in the code/logic/design.

I know I can debug step-by-step "forwardly", I want to do the same backwards, so the debugger would need to save its context in each step.

Comment: I think gdb can do this.  Just add -g to your compile flags

Comment: Many, (all?), IDE-based development environments have a built-in debugger that can show the stack frames, (locals, function returns), by source code line.  Then there's gdb for command-line stuff..

Comment: That's one of the main functions of any debugger. Which debuggers have you looked at? There is a list on Wikipedia that you can consult.

Comment: I know of no such program, and I _highly_ doubt there will be one in the next 20 years.  The memory usage on such a thing would be _incredible_.

Comment: I don't need to track heap usage/changes, just the stack state. Take a look at ODB, it seems to do what I need, but only with Java code.

Comment: I have used such a tool, it is not "20 years in the future" as suggested here, but I am not sure if it is publicly available.  See: http://www.osronline.com/showthread.cfm?link=129469

Comment: @MooingDuck I'm pretty sure there is (http://research.cs.wisc.edu/areas/pl/seminar/fall05/Bhansali.ppt). Too bad I cannot share it..

Comment: @MooingDuck, GDB has had it for three years http://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/ReverseDebug and TotalView has similar functionality, http://www.roguewave.com/products/totalview/replayengine.aspx

Comment: Worth noting that you've completely changed the meaning of the question by specifying stepping backwards - which makes most of the comments and answers nonsense...

Comment: Sorry for the badly written question, I didn't mean to confuse you. I had the problem for so long that the question was clear enough in my head.

Comment: on windows the tool is time travel debugging https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/time-travel-debugging-overview

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In addition to the stack traces to examine past instructions already mentioned here on x86 targets newer gdb also supports [recorded program execution and stepping backwards](http://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/ProcessRecord/Tutorial) which should come pretty close to what you are looking for.

Answer (score 6):

> - http://sources.redhat.com/gdb/news/reversible.html
>
> GDB version 7.0 (due September 2009) will be the first public release
>   of gdb to support reverse debugging (the ability to make the program
>   being debugged step and continue in reverse)

ADDENDUM:

Visual Studio 2010 and higher supports "Historical Debugging" ("IntelliTrace"):

- http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jrobbins/archive/2009/06/16/how-does-vs2010-historical-debugging-work.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264915%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: Visual Studio can only do this for .NET applications written in C# or Visual Basic. As the article says, "IntelliTrace does not support debugging C++"

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use GDB for C/C++.
You have some stack trace options and you'll be able to set breakpoints in your program and run it step by step.

Check at http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~gilpin/tutorial/#3.5  or find other tutorials on the web.

Hope it helps.

Comment: @templatetypedef this answer was given before stepping backwards was editted in as a requirement (sigh), though actually GDB *does* support this (requires GDB >=7): http://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/ReverseDebug

Answer (score 0):

`gdb` has commands `up n` and `down n` to select (`n`)frames `up` or `down`.

Probably this can help.

Answer (score -2):

For linux [`GDB`](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/pub/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb/html_node/gdb_42.html) is suggested while for Windows [`windbg`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff539042%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is better.

Comment: I spent loads of time getting WinDbg to work with my current project, only to find out that it does not support reverse debugging.